# How do you uninstall a python package that was installed using distutils?

Tags: python

Can you simply delete the directory from your python installation, or are there any lingering files that you must delete?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It varies based on the options that you pass to `install` and the contents of the [distutils configuration files](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#inst-config-files) on the system/in the package. I don't believe that any files are modified outside of directories specified in these ways.

Notably, [distutils does not have an uninstall command](http://bugs.python.org/issue4673) at this time.

It's also noteworthy that deleting a package/egg can cause dependency issues – utilities like [`easy_install`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) attempt to alleviate such problems.

Comment: Can you please update this to directly address the lingering files part of the question?

Comment: I thought I did -- no files are created outside of the directories specified by the distutils configuration and install flags, so any "lingering" files will exist in these directories. It varies from package to package.

Comment: @cdleary: thanks, but, I was hoping you'd simply clarify and strengthen your answer, not add a long comment thread.

Comment: @S.Lott: Sorry, but I don't know which part of the answer you want clarification on -- can you be more specific?

Comment: **[msg139773](http://bugs.python.org/issue4673#msg139773) Date: 2011-07-04 14:35 distutils2/packaging now provides a remove function and a pysetup remove command.**

Answer (score 21):

The three things that get installed that you will need to delete are:

1. Packages/modules
2. Scripts
3. Data files

Now on my linux system these live in:

1. /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages
2. /usr/bin
3. /usr/share

But on a windows system they are more likely to be entirely within the Python distribution directory. I have no idea about OSX except it is more likey to follow the linux pattern.

Answer (score 13):

Another time stamp based hack:

1. Create an anchor: `touch /tmp/ts`
2. Reinstall the package to be removed: `python setup.py install --prefix=<PREFIX>`
3. Remove files what are more recent than the anchor file: `find <PREFIX> -cnewer /tmp/ts | xargs rm -r`

Comment: -1. I don't like the `| xargs rm -r`. I recommend going over each file *manually*. On ext4 (and other file systems), this `find` is going to list all *folders* too. If your prefix was `/usr`, you're **going to delete `/usr/*`**.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is safe to simply delete anything that distutils installed. That goes for installed folders or .egg files. Naturally anything that depends on that code will no longer work.

If you want to make it work again, simply re-install.

By the way, if you are using distutils also consider using the multi-version feature. It allows you to have multiple versions of any single package installed. That means you do not need to delete an old version of a package if you simply want to install a newer version.

Answer (score 5):

In ubuntu 12.04, I have found that the only place you need to look by default is under

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

And simply remove the associated folder and file, if there is one!

Comment: Sometimes in /usr/lib/python<2.7/3.6>

Answer (score 5):

**`install --record` + `xargs rm`**

```
sudo python setup.py install --record files.txt
xargs sudo rm -rf < files.txt
```

removes all files and but leaves empty directories behind.

That is not ideal, it should be enough to avoid package conflicts.

And then you can finish the job manually if you want by reading `files.txt`, or be braver and automate empty directory removal as well.

A safe helper would be:

```
python-setup-uninstall() (
  sudo rm -f files.txt
  sudo python setup.py install --record files.txt && \
  xargs rm -rf < files.txt
  sudo rm -f files.txt
)
```

Tested in Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

If this is for testing and/or development purposes, [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) has a [develop](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode) command that updates every time you make a change (so you don't have to uninstall and reinstall every time you make a change).  And you can uninstall the package using this command as well.

If you do use this, anything that you declare as a *script* will be left behind as a lingering file.

Answer (score 4):

for Python in Windows:

```
python -m pip uninstall "package_keyword"
uninstall **** (y/n)?
```

Comment: It does not work if the package has been installed using distutils.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 7,

**Control Panel --> Programs --> Uninstall**

, then

choose the python package to remove.

Comment: @Mauricio I do not see old versions in the list but I can see the egg files in the site-packages. Is this a problem?

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I just uninstalled a python package, and even though I'm not *certain* I did so perfectly, I'm reasonably confident.

I started by getting a list of *all* python-related files, ordered by date, on the assumption that all of the files in my package will have more or less the same timestamp, and no other files will.

Luckily, I've got python installed under `/opt/Python-2.6.1`; if I had been using the Python that comes with my Linux distro, I'd have had to scour all of `/usr`, which would have taken a long time.

Then I just examined that list, and noted with relief that all the stuff that I wanted to nuke consisted of one directory, `/opt/Python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/module-name/`, and one file, `/opt/Python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/module-x.x.x_blah-py2.6.egg-info`.

So I just deleted those.

Here's how I got the date-sorted list of files:

`find "$@" -printf '%T@ ' -ls | sort -n | cut -d\  -f 2-`

(I think that's got to be GNU "find", by the way; the flavor you get on OS X doesn't know about "-printf '%T@'")

I use that *all* the time.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX, manually delete these 2 directories under your ***pathToPython/site-packages/*** will work:

- {packageName}
- {packageName}-{version}-info

for example, to remove ***pyasn1***, which is a distutils installed project:

- rm -rf lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1
- rm -rf lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.7.egg-info

To find out where is your site-packages:

```
python -m site
```

Comment: Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What it worked for me on Windows 10 and using Python for Windows version 3.96 was to just erase the folder containing the module inside the `site-package` folder. In my case this was located at: `C:\Python396\Lib\site-packages`.
After this a `pip list` does not show the module that I wanted to delete anymore.

Answer (score -1):

`ERROR: flake8 3.7.9 has requirement pycodestyle<2.6.0,>=2.5.0, but you'll have pycodestyle 2.3.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: nuscenes-devkit 1.0.8 has requirement motmetrics<=1.1.3, but you'll have motmetrics 1.2.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: descartes, future, torch, cachetools, torchvision, flake8-import-order, xmltodict, entrypoints, flake8, motmetrics, nuscenes-devkit
  Attempting uninstall: torch
    Found existing installation: torch 1.0.0
    Uninstalling torch-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled torch-1.0.0
  Attempting uninstall: torchvision
    Found existing installation: torchvision 0.2.1
    Uninstalling torchvision-0.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled torchvision-0.2.1
  Attempting uninstall: entrypoints
    Found existing installation: entrypoints 0.2.3
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'entrypoints'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Then I type:

`conda uninstall entrypoints
pip install --upgrade pycodestyle
pip install nuscenes-devkit`

Done!

Comment: Please try to explain what you are doing and why instead of just showing the console output.