# Pylons: accidentally typed 'setup.py install', how can I fix?

Tags: python, pylons

While working on a Pylons app, I accidentally typed

```
python setup.py install
```

in the home directory of a project, instead of what I meant to type, namely

```
python setup.py egg_info
```

Oops. It looks like the Pylons app has now been installed as a Python package. Whenever I make changes to the project, they don't get propagated unless I re-run `install`, which is annoying.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you uninstall a python package that was installed using distutils?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402359/how-do-you-uninstall-a-python-package-that-was-installed-using-distutils)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete the related content from the dist-packages/site-packages and .egg info files manually