# E: Unable to locate package npm2deb

Tags: node.js, debian-stretch

I want to uninstall npm2deb from my debian stretch .
I installed by using the command

python3 setup.py install

it is giving me error when trying to uninstall
using `apt-get remove npm2deb`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package npm2deb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your setup.py is running with [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html), you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4005527/7105919).

Comment: I get this error after i followed what is said in that post

 You can remove it from your system anytime using: 

      dpkg -r qwert

**********************************************************************

root@debian:/home/midhun/npm2deb#  dpkg -r qwert
(Reading database ... 153005 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing qwert (20180103-1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing qwert, directory '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages' not empty so not removed

Comment: This seems to be a warning, so I don't think you need to worry about it. npm2deb should be uninstalled