# How to reset site-packages

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to "reset" `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages`? i.e. to remove all packages and modules installed either by `setup.py install` or using `easy_install`?

Motivation: something went wrong with all the package versions and dependencies and I rather reset and reinstall everything than spend the time in figuring out what it was exactly...

Comment: You could just delete all the contents in the folder, although there may still be files in Tools/Scripts and other places left over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just delete all the contents in the folder, although there may still be files in Tools/Scripts and other places left over.

Have a look here:[StackOverflow: uninstall a python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402359/how-do-you-uninstall-a-python-package-that-was-installed-using-distutils)

Comment: Is simply deleting everything ok?

Comment: Deleting things should be fine for the vast majority of cases. There may be the odd package that installs files outside site-packages, but it's pretty unlikely.

Comment: you should [uninstall everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250821/3064538) with `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` before you delete `site-packages/`.

Comment: Where is site-packages located? (I need to remove a package from it as instructed [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247) but I cannot find it)

Answer (score 0):

Does a simple `rm -rf *` in the site-packages directory do what you want, or do you want to leave some packages untouched?

Comment: I rather reinstall everything. Is simply deleting everything ok?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) for future reference.