# How do I remove all packages installed by pip?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-packaging

How do I uninstall all packages installed by pip from my currently activated virtual environment?

Comment: @patelshahrukh uninstalling python **DOES NOT** remove pip packages. please **AVOID** doing that, since it both most likely **WON'T WORK** the way you think it will, *and*, depending on how you install python again, can leave your machine in an unstable state that's **more work to fix**.

Comment: this might help for packages installed in development mode or editable mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619/how-to-uninstall-editable-packages-with-pip-installed-with-e

Answer (score 1792, accepted):

I've found this snippet as an alternative solution. It's a more graceful removal of libraries than remaking the virtualenv:

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

---

In case you have packages installed via VCS, you need to exclude those lines and remove the packages manually (elevated from the comments below):

```
pip freeze --exclude-editable | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

---

If you have packages installed directly from github/gitlab, those will have `@`.
Like:

`django @ git+https://github.com/django.git@<sha>`

You can add `cut -d "@" -f1` to get just the package name that is required to uninstall it.

```
pip freeze | cut -d "@" -f1 | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Comment: I find this a good solution, purely because it doesn't remove the virtual environment entirely - I may have made changes to e.g. `postactivate` which will remain.

Comment: After running this I realized it removed the `setuptools` package. I resolved the issue following instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Comment: @gerty3000 yes, this will (as the question asks) remove all of the packages installed in a virtual-env. in your environment, maybe setuptools would be better off installed at a global location instead?

Comment: this is apprently what `wipeenv` of `virtualenvwrapper` does but it does not handle `-e` like this answer suggests. so how to uninstalle those VCS ones?

Comment: I've noticed that pip fails early when a lib isn't already installed, so `for r in $(cat requirements.txt | grep -v ^#); do pip uninstall -y $r; done;` works in that case.

Comment: @Pat you're probably not running the pip freeze at the start; this command explicitly removes all the already installed packages (and not the ones that were meant to be installed/listed in requirements)

Comment: @blueberryfields you're right, I wasn't. But that's because I didn't want to uninstall everything, I only wanted to uninstall libs that are listed in reqs.txt. Different use case, I guess :)

Comment: To speed up the uninstall (helps a lot if you have an SSD and a multicore processor): `pip freeze | grep -v "^-e" | xargs -L1 -P16 pip uninstall -y`

Comment: You can also use `pip freeze --exclude-editable | xargs pip uninstall -y` to ignore VCS packages without using a grep pattern

Comment: I had to run `pip freeze | xargs -I {} pip uninstall -y {}` but otherwise this worked for me.

Comment: @HarshadKavathiya use cygwin or gow

Comment: And to uninstall editable packages see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346619

Comment: Does not work with Azure Notebooks: `ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'bitarray'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: `ERROR: Invalid requirement: '@'` I have packages that ive installed from my gitlab.

Comment: `pip freeze` lists all packages, including those installed in the OS. User will is unable (and possibly does not want) to remove them without root permissions. `pip freeze --user` worked for me.

Comment: It has been suggested to me that your answer also answers my Q at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662158/fixing-python-packages-mis-installed-by-sudo-pip-sudo-pip3  Is this true, as I don't see sudo discussed here at all.

Comment: VCS should be explained [here](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool)

Comment: Does it delete the pip package (which I want to keep)

Comment: I voted this up 2 years ago and here I am again, wishing I could vote this up one more time. :D

Comment: In case you have been looking to uninstall on multiple versions of python, use `py -<version> -m pip freeze | xargs py -<version> -m pip uninstall -y`. Make sure to add `py -<version> -m` in both occurrences, if in case you add it only in the first, you would see something as `WARNING: Skipping <package> as it is not installed.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67379806/1862590 This solution is provided to reset the virtual environment.

Comment: @mRyan `pip list --format=freeze |xargs pip uninstall -y` did the trick for me

Comment: Warning: don't run this command in your base conda environment, it will remove packages required for conda itself to work.

Comment: If you are using Windows, you can't run this in a command prompt because you don't have use xargs, cut, etc. However if you have git installed, you probably have git bash installed as well and you can run this command in a git bash shell

Comment: I run into a problem that `typing-extensions` becomes `typing_extensions` (note the `-` and `_`) after `pip freeze` in some versions of Python. Although both names are legal, this package will be uninstalled even if it is in `requirements.txt`. We need to match `_` against `-` before `grep`, maybe by ` | sed "s/_/-/g"`.

Answer (score 906):

This will work for all Mac, Windows, and Linux systems.
To get the list of all pip packages in the requirements.txt file (Note: This will overwrite requirements.txt if exist else will create the new one, also if you don't want to replace old requirements.txt then give different file name in the all following command in place requirements.txt).

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now to remove one by one

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

If we want to remove all at once then

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
```

If you're working on an existing project that has a `requirements.txt` file and your environment has diverged, simply replace `requirements.txt` from the above examples with `toberemoved.txt`. Then, once you have gone through the steps above, you can use the `requirements.txt` to update your now clean environment.

And For single command without creating any file as @joeb [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip#comment75874178_40566052)

```
pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

Comment: probably worth mentioning that you are force overwriting their requirements.txt file, in case they didn't know. :)

Comment: In addition, if one wants to remove all packages, appending "-y" will do so. Example: `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`

Comment: You can use `pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)` to do everything in one go.

Comment: @joeb yes we can do that way also.

Comment: @HarshadKavathiya you can use another file to store pip freeze, like "current.txt", so requirements.txt can stay untouched
cheers

Comment: @NikosKeyz Yes we can use any other file name.

Comment: note that the powershell will deny acces to the requirements.text. With the regular cmd it worked tho

Comment: @joeb THanks for the suggestion. Added your suggestion answer

Comment: with bash we can use io redirection to save us relying on filesystem state: `python3 -m pip uninstall -r <(python3 -m pip freeze)`

Comment: When I try to use the pip uninstall it says that the requirements.txt file is not exists, but it is.

Comment: @nakE This is strange to me, but If the file is there in the correct directory you should not get this error for sure.

Comment: @nakE It would be great you share the screenshot with the error you are facing, it really helps to understand the issue.

Comment: @HarshadKavathiya Is it fine now, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 221):

I wanted to elevate this answer out of a comment section because it's one of the most elegant solutions in the thread.  Full credit for this answer goes to [@joeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174652/joeb).

```bash
pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

This worked great for me for the use case of clearing my user packages folder outside the context of a virtualenv which many of the above answers don't handle.

*Edit: Anyone know how to make this command work in a Makefile?*

### Bonus: A bash alias

I add this to my bash profile for convenience:

```bash
alias pipuninstallall="pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)"
```

Then run:

```bash
pipuninstallall
```

### Alternative for Pipenv

If you are using [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), you can run:

```bash
pipenv uninstall --all
```

### Alternative for Poetry

If you are using [Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry), run:

```bash
poetry env remove --python3.9
```

(Note that you need to change the version number there to match whatever your Python version is.)

Comment: I like it but it doesn't work in the null case (`pip freeze` results in nothing output if no packages installed, and then `pip uninstall` complains, unfortunately).

Comment: Hmm good catch.  Perhaps it could be wrapped into a bash function that checks whether the pip freeze output is non-empty.  I don't see a great way to achieve that while keeping the command a nice short one-liner.

Comment: make uses sh by default, but the substitution syntax `<(...)` is a bashism. So you can either use bash -c "...", or work around by doing a `pip freeze | pip uninstall -r /dev/stdin`

Comment: Does not work with Azure Notebooks: `ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'bitarray'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: @SeaDude Here is a workaround that may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915951/cannot-uninstall-chardet.  If that doesn't work, then this approach would be my next best guess - https://github.com/vlachoudis/bCNC/issues/1141.  Note that the packages mentioned are different, but I believe the underlying issue may be similar.

Comment: Add `SHELL := /usr/bin/env bash` at the top of your Makefile. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Comment: Does not works on Windows `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 157):

This works with the latest. I think it's the shortest and most declarative way to do it.

```
virtualenv --clear MYENV
```

But why not just delete and recreate the virtualenv?

Immutability rules. Besides it's hard to remember all those piping and grepping the other solutions use.

Comment: Is this effectively the same as running `wipeenv`? http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#wipeenv

Comment: Actually — it seems (from what I just ran into) whereas `wipeenv` while within the environment throws an error and doesn't remove anything if used in the context of a `pip install -e` development build, attempting to use `virtualenv --clear MYENV` doesn't throw an error and removes none of the packages that you may have installed previously in the environment. At least this is the case on OSX. See https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issues/211/wipeenv-does-not-work-when-pip-install-e for further info.

Comment: `wipeenv` is an alias provided by virtualenvwrapper, so not everyone has it.

Comment: well, this is kind of a dirty trick, but works like magic. I would prefer that everyone to use pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y. It makes a great clean up.

Answer (score 77):

I managed it by doing the following:

1. Create the requirements file called `reqs.txt` with currently installed packages list

```sh
pip freeze > reqs.txt
```

2. Then uninstall all the packages from `reqs.txt`

```sh
# -y means remove the package without prompting for confirmation
pip uninstall -y -r reqs.txt
```

I like this method as you always have a pip requirements file to fall back on should you make a mistake. It's also repeatable, and it's cross-platform (Windows, Linux, MacOs).

Answer (score 67):

Other answers that use `pip list` or `pip freeze` **must include `--local`** else it will also uninstall packages that are found in the common namespaces.

So here are the snippet I regularly use

```
 pip freeze --local | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Ref: `pip freeze --help`

Comment: This worked until it hit a package that produced this error: `ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'bitarray'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`. Then I couldn't uninstall any more modules.

Comment: This will include the packages from distribution repositiories. The `--user` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60966049/721644 then comes very handy despite the complaints in the first comment there. But for some reason even that included packages installed in /usr/li64/... even though the number of packages was much smaller.

Answer (score 46):

#### Method 1 (with `pip freeze`)

```bash
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

#### Method 2 (with `pip list`)

```bash
pip list | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

#### Method 3 (with `virtualenv`)

```bash
virtualenv --clear MYENV
```

Comment: Method 2 (`pip list`) works great until you have pip accidentally uninstall itself -_-

Comment: Method 2 didn't work in my case because there is a header in the list which needs to be ignored. This one worked: `pip list | awk '{print $1}' | grep -vE "^pip$|^Package$|^---" | xargs pip uninstall -y`

Answer (score 40):

On Windows if your `path` is configured correctly, you can use:

```bash
pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && del unins
```

It should be a similar case for Unix-like systems:

```bash
pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && rm unins
```

Just a warning that this isn't completely solid as you may run into issues such as 'File not found' but it may work in some cases nonetheless

EDIT: For clarity: `unins` is an arbitrary file which has data written out to it when this command executes: `pip freeze > unins`

That file that it written in turn is then used to uninstall the aforementioned packages with implied consent/prior approval via `pip uninstall -y -r unins`

The file is finally deleted upon completion.

Answer (score 34):

I use the --user option to uninstall all the packages installed in the user site.

```
pip3 freeze --user | xargs pip3 uninstall -y
```

Comment: I believe this answer doesn't add much new information, I would rather have suggested an improvement to another already existing similar answer such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45475070/11138259

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv and get `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to uninstall`, remove the --user part

Comment: `pip3 freeze | xargs pip3 uninstall -y` ==>
` PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/ap' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-q9gzbj0d/ap'`

Comment: @SL5net. You might need to run it as superuser. Something like sudo sh -c 'pip3 freeze | xargs pip3 uninstall -y' (The added sh -c and quotes are because pipe doesnt tend to play nicely with sudo) Or you could just do your command as root, but I dont recomend that as its not a great habit to be in. shelling about in root makes it pretty easy to accidently murder your system, trust me, bitter experience talking here.

Comment: Good point of `--user` option. Because `--local` lists *all* packages installed locally, not user ones.

Answer (score 30):

Best way to remove all packages from the virtual environment.

## Windows PowerShell:

```bash
pip freeze > unins ; pip uninstall -y -r unins ; del unins
```

## Windows Command Prompt:

```bash
pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && del unins
```

## Linux:

```bash
pip3 freeze > unins ; pip3 uninstall -y -r unins ; rm unins
```

Comment: Windows `no such option: -y` ran without `-y` option but it didn't delete any packages

Comment: @flywire it worked for me in votes and see the votes. FYI, I tried this windows 10 and windows 11 operating systems.

Comment: It is not Windows it is PowerShell. Windows - cmd: `&`, PowerShell: `;`

Answer (score 24):

For Windows users, this is what I use on **Windows PowerShell**

```
 pip uninstall -y (pip freeze)
```

Answer (score 20):

The quickest way is to remake the virtualenv completely.  I'm assuming you have a requirements.txt file that matches production, if not:

```bash
# On production:
pip freeze > reqs.txt

# On your machine:
rm $VIRTUALENV_DIRECTORY
mkdir $VIRTUALENV_DIRECTORY
pip install -r reqs.txt
```

Comment: Does this even handle the case where there was a editable install (basically a setuptools develop mode install) that created a local .egg-info file that then interfered with the rest  of the installation/uninstallation process? Since it's a set of files it doesn't seem to know how to handle their presence, and rather than uninstalling anything it makes a local directory structure under MYENV complete with: `
> New python executables in MYENV/bin/python3.4 
> Also creating executable in MYENV/bin/python 
> Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.`
But MYENV hasn't reset the environment!

Answer (score 20):

First, add all package to `requirements.txt`

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then remove all

```
pip uninstall -y -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 17):

Using [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) function:

```
wipeenv
```

See [wipeenv documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html?highlight=wipeenv#wipeenv)

Comment: If you are using virtualenvwrapper, type [```wipeenv```](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#managing-installed-packages)

Answer (score 14):

Its an old question I know but I did stumble across it so for future reference you can now do this:

```
pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...
```

> -r, --requirement file
>
> > Uninstall all the packages listed in the given requirements file. This option can be used multiple times.

from the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/) version 8.1

Answer (score 10):

```bash
pip uninstall `pip freeze --user`
```

The `--user` option prevents system-installed packages from being included in the listing, thereby avoiding `/usr/lib` and `distutils` permission errors.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988269.

Answer (score 7):

(adding this as an answer, because I do not have enough reputation to comment on @blueberryfields 's answer)

@blueberryfields 's answer works well, but fails if there is no package to uninstall (which can be a problem if this "uninstall all" is part of a script or makefile). This can be solved with `xargs -r` when using GNU's version of `xargs`:

```
pip freeze --exclude-editable | xargs -r pip uninstall -y
```

from `man xargs`:

> -r, --no-run-if-empty
>
> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there
>   is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 7):

```
pip3 freeze --local | xargs pip3 uninstall -y
```

The case might be that one has to run this command several times to get an empty `pip3 freeze --local`.

Comment: This breaks on editably installed packages right now

Answer (score 3):

This was the easiest way for me to uninstall all python packages.

```
from pip import get_installed_distributions
from os import system
for i in get_installed_distributions():
    system("pip3 uninstall {} -y -q".format(i.key))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works on my windows system

```bash
pip freeze > packages.txt && pip uninstall -y -r packages.txt && del packages.txt
```

The first part `pip freeze > packages.txt` creates a text file with list of packages installed using pip along with the version number

The second part `pip uninstall -y -r packages.txt` deletes all the packages installed without asking for a confirmation prompt.

The third part `del packages.txt` deletes the just now created packages.txt.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-platform support by using only `pip`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import stderr
from pip.commands.uninstall import UninstallCommand
from pip import get_installed_distributions

pip_uninstall = UninstallCommand()
options, args = pip_uninstall.parse_args([
    package.project_name
    for package in
    get_installed_distributions()
    if not package.location.endswith('dist-packages')
])

options.yes = True  # Don't confirm before uninstall
# set `options.require_venv` to True for virtualenv restriction

try:
    print pip_uninstall.run(options, args)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != 13:
        raise e
    print >> stderr, "You lack permissions to uninstall this package.
                      Perhaps run with sudo? Exiting."
    exit(13)
# Plenty of other exceptions can be thrown, e.g.: `InstallationError`
# handle them if you want to.
```

Answer (score 2):

the easy robust way
cross-platform
and work in pipenv as well is:

```
pip freeze 
pip uninstall -r requirement
```

by pipenv:

```
pipenv run pip freeze 
pipenv run pip uninstall -r requirement
```

but won't update piplock or pipfile so be aware

Answer (score 2):

On Windows if your path is configured correctly, you can use:

```bash
pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && del unins
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `rm -r .venv` and start over?

Comment: I am not very experienced in Python but this is what I had in mind too.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, using command prompt, deleting all the installed packages in a virtual environment (after the environment is active):

```
for /f %i in ('pip freeze --local') do pip uninstall -y %i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that works for me:

```bash
pip list | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `virtualenv`:

```
virtualenv --clear </path/to/your/virtualenv>
```

for example, if your virtualenv is `/Users/you/.virtualenvs/projectx`, then you'd run:

```
virtualenv --clear /Users/you/.virtualenvs/projectx
```

if you don't know where your virtual env is located, you can run `which python` from within an activated virtual env to get the path

Answer (score 0):

> In **Command Shell** of Windows, the command `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` won't work. So for those of you using Windows, I've figured out an alternative way to do so.

1. Copy all the names of the installed packages of **pip** from the `pip freeze` command to a **.txt** file.
2. Then, go the location of your **.txt** file and run the command `pip uninstall -r *textfile.txt*`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pew`, you can use the [wipeenv](https://github.com/berdario/pew#wipeenv) command:

`pew wipeenv [env]`

Answer (score 0):

I simply wanted to remove packages installed by the project, and not other packages I've installed (things like `neovim`, `mypy` and `pudb`  which I use for local dev but are not included in the app requirements). So I did:

`cat requirements.txt| sed 's/=.*//g' | xargs pip uninstall -y`

which worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Select Libraries To Delete From This Folder:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages

Comment: Although this does delete all packages (and more), it doesn't do so with pip as the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop to remove all packages installed by pip.

Here is the command for Windows:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('pip freeze') do pip uninstall -y "%i"
```

`%i` is used as a loop variable, and you should run this command in the same directory where pip is located, or you can provide the full path to pip if it's not in your system's PATH.

Answer (score -1):

Pip has no way of knowing what packages were installed by it and what packages were installed by your system's package manager. For this you would need to do something like this

for rpm-based distros (replace python2.7 with your python version you installed pip with):

```bash
find /usr/lib/python2.7/ |while read f; do
  if ! rpm -qf "$f" &> /dev/null; then
    echo "$f"
  fi
done |xargs rm -fr
```

for a deb-based distribution:

```bash
find /usr/lib/python2.7/ |while read f; do
  if ! dpkg-query -S "$f" &> /dev/null; then
    echo "$f"
  fi
done |xargs rm -fr
```

then to clean up empty directories left over:

```bash
find /usr/lib/python2.7 -type d -empty |xargs rm -fr
```

I found the top answer very misleading since it will remove all (most?) python packages from your distribution and probably leave you with a broken system.

Comment: With all due respect, this seems comparable. Why not `dpkg-query -S '/usr/lib/python2.7/*'`, extract the names, and `dpkg-query -L` each name to dump the associated files? It already has the manifests prepared. My main objection is that instead of targeting packages installed anywhere but by pip, you've targeted packages installed by anything other than the manager you expect, and in a location that pip generally shouldn't be touching. `pip list -l` lists the packages it installed locally, and some will even `pip install --target=...`. Removing all currently empty dirs will bite you too!

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I had accidentally installed a number of packages globally using a Homebrew-installed `pip` on macOS. The easiest way to revert to the default packages was a simple:

```
$ brew reinstall python
```

Or, if you were using `pip3`:

```
$ brew reinstall python3
```

Comment: This answer assumes too much about the environment and doesn't directly solve the problem if you are using pyenv for example.

Comment: @Mark Well sure if you're using pyenv, then you would need to do something different. In the common case that you're not, I believe this is the simplest and least hacky solution. Note that this condition is explicitly stated at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: The OP asked about virtualenvs.  He made no specific mention of using a Mac or brew to install Python.  Therefore you cannot assume the OS or brew was used - and this answer will not solve ALL conditions.  If you focus on solving for the environment using a tool such as pip - you will address the context of the environment you are within.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Mark I understand your position. We can agree to disagree. I just want to help out the people from Google who click on a link labelled "What is the easiest way to remove all packages installed by pip?" when they really want to remove all packages installed *globally* by pip.

Comment: Agreed with @RadonRosborough, the link title is representative of why I landed here, even if the OP does not actually ask the same question.