# How to uninstall pip on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I ran the following commands:

```
easy_install pip
sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
```

How do I reverse the two commands to get my python back to its original state in OSX? (removing pip as part of it)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The first thing you should try is:

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

On many environments that doesn't work. So given the lack of info on that problem, I ended up removing pip manually from /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Probably the worst way to uninstall `pip`. Try `pip uninstall pip`

Comment: That didn't work, that's why we had to use this method.

Comment: Make sure you used the sudo -H flag

Comment: if pip doesn't work because it expects a version of python that doesn't exist, you need to manually delete it. python is a mess.

Answer (score 42):

In my case I ran the following command and it worked (not that I was expecting it to):

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

Which resulted in:

```
Uninstalling pip-6.1.1:
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1.dist-info/METADATA
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1.dist-info/RECORD
  <and all the other stuff>
  ...

  /usr/local/bin/pip
  /usr/local/bin/pip2
  /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pip-6.1.1
```

Comment: I'm also somewhat surprised to report that this works like a charm. +1

Comment: `pip` is awesome :P

Comment: Accidentally installed `pip` using `sudo easy_install pip` with the version that ships with macOS Sierra. This solution appears to have resolved my predicament.


Other information, if anybody else reads this or cares: 
`Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin`

Answer (score 12):

In order to completely remove pip, I believe you have to delete its files from all Python versions on your computer. For me, they are here:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/
```

You may need to remove the files or the directories located at these file-paths (and more, depending on the number of versions of Python you have installed).

**Edit**: to find all versions of pip on your machine, use:
`find / -name pip 2>/dev/null`, which starts at its highest level (hence the `/`) and hides all error messages (that's what `2>/dev/null` does). This is my output:

```
$ find / -name pip 2>/dev/null
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip
```

Answer (score 10):

Aditionally to the answer from @srk, you should uninstall package `setuptools`:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

If you want to uninstall all other packages first, this answer has some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250821/265954

Note: before you use the commands from that answer, please carefully read the comments about side effects and how to avoid uninstalling `pip` and `setuptools` too early. E.g. `pip freeze | grep -v "^-e" | grep -v "^(setuptools|pip)" | xargs pip uninstall -y`

Comment: Mind that you might have various Python versions installed. Then you need to write the exact version in front, like `python3.7 -m uninstall pip setuptools` if you also have a `python3.6` installed which would dominate the `python3.7` if the environmental variables are set like this, see [pip/python: normal site-packages is not writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable/65290638#65290638)

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Big Sur Version 11.0.1

```
$ which pip
output: /usr/local/bin/pip
```

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
```

There I found pip, pip2, pip2.7

```
$ sudo rm -r pip # for each version to remove
```

Somehow the installation with easy_install was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Since pip is a package,
`pip uninstall pip`
Will do it.
EDIT: If that does not work, try `sudo -H pip uninstall pip`.

Answer (score 0):

First see the path of the python site-packages files by running this python code

```
import os 
import inspect 
print(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect))+"/site-packages")
```

a path will be printed, take it and add it as a parameter to your pip command

`pip install package_name -t "the printed path"`

Eg: `pip install pandas -t "the printed path"`