# Getting Error when Running Python code on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, pip, anaconda

This is my first time to use Ubuntu

I am using Spyder

I am following instructions I find on the ineternet

Now I am stuck

I am trying to get Python Anaconda working on Ubuntu

I installed it

trying now to test my first code

simple code

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")

print(df.head())
```

but I get `ModuleNotFoundError : No Module named pandas`

I have installed panadas in both ways

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

and

```
pip3 install pandas
```

both ways installed

yet I am still getting same error

```
ModuleNotFoundError : No Module named pandas
```

[image]

Comment: What is the outcome when you run `pip3 install pandas` ?

Comment: Similarly, what is the outcome if you run `python -c "import pandas"`

Comment: @erncyp many thanks it works using python -c "import pandas"

Comment: @erncyp I am having the same problem with autosklearn but does not work I am getting "no module names autosklearn" although I installed as its website mentioned

Comment: Have you tried to install using `pip` instead of `pip3`? How are you running those commands? Can you give us more details?!

Comment: @asmgx, please see my answer below. Maybe you just need to restart jupyter kernel if you are using jupyter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Notebook can't find modules for python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914761/jupyter-notebook-cant-find-modules-for-python-3-6)

Comment: Installed Anaconda how, where? Running your Python code how, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, it appears that all you needed to was restart the kernel. When you install a new package, if you are using ipython, jupyternotebook, or spyder you should restart the kernel. This is why `python -c "import pandas"` worked, whereas in your python session, it wasn't working.

A running python kernel does not search for new packages since it started running. Starting and stopping will make sure it will find the new packages. There are probably ways to find new packages without restarting the kernel, probably by using some of `importlab` functions, but not sure if this would be necessary.

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest that the OP is using Jupyter. Do you have information we don't have?

Comment: True, it might not be jupyter. perhaps @asmgx can clarify. Will delete/edit answer if updated

Comment: @erncyp I am using Spyder