# How to change Python version in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

at the beginning I had installed the newest Python 3.9 version. However, on this version I was not able to install tensorflow, which I read is not supporting this version. After it, I installed Python 3.8.7 but my jupyter notebook is still using Python 3.9. How can I change version in Jupyter Notebook to use 3.8.7 instead of 3.9? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install python 3.8? using a virtual environment like conda?

Comment: No, I just installed it through normal installator from python webpage

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment manager like conda at all? This way you can easily create environments with different versions of Python.

Comment: No, I am using jupyter notebook just by typing in cmd "jupyter notebook" and I would like to know how to easily switch this version inside the notebook

Comment: Use virtualenv and start jupyter inside it. E.g. `pipenv run jupyter-notebook` - this way it will be guaranteed that you start with correct python interpreter and correct set of libraries. `poetry` could be used the same way too.

Comment: @Lukasz Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 15):

```
pip3 install ipykernel --upgrade
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

References:

[Jupyter Notebook can't find modules for python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914761/jupyter-notebook-cant-find-modules-for-python-3-6)