# /usr/local/bin/python2: No module named pip (Raspberry Pi/Jessie)

Tags: python, linux, pip

Iv'e gotten lots of help from stackoverflow but I'm stumped and this is my first post. I'm trying to install OverGrive from a `.deb` file and keep hitting a wall with a "`/usr/local/bin/python2: No module named pip`" on the installation. I'm fairly certain I've met all of the dependencies and have uninstalled and reinstalled pip both directly and through my package manager several times. There is obviously some kind of path/registry type problem but I can't resolve it. Scale of 10, my experience is 4. Thanks!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i overgrive_3.2.3_all.deb    
(Reading database ... 136303 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack overgrive_3.2.3_all.deb ...  
/var/lib/dpkg/info/overgrive.prerm: line 5: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)  
Unpacking overgrive (3.2.3) over (3.2.3) ...  
Setting up overgrive (3.2.3) ...  
/usr/local/bin/python2: No module named pip    
dpkg: error processing package overgrive (--install):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...  
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...  
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:armhf (2.42.1-1) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 overgrive  
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ pip -V  
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg   (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Is this what you did to install? `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools`

Comment: No, that was not exactly what I tried. Let me give it a try and get back to you in a while..

Comment: You have to install pip: `apt-get install python-pip` as root.

Comment: That may be more than you need, but I have had no trouble on Rasp Pi with PIP after running that combination.

Comment: I was unsuccessful-same result.  First uninstalled pip which proved difficult perhaps because I had made installation attempts both directly and through the package manager. Following this post however I believe I obtained complete removal including chasing down remnant pip files.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012597/how-to-uninstall-pip-on-osx-mavericks  Reinstalled python-pip (as root)  and ran the OverGrive installation.I Hit the same snag as reported.  An incomplete installation. When the application icon is clicked results in a hourglass mouse pointer that times out.