# Cannot use Easy_install to Install Pip

Tags: python, macos, pip, installation

Having problems installing pip and other environment things for OSX. Going through different guides on SE (including these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012597/how-to-uninstall-pip-on-osx-mavericks), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)), and everyone's solution seems to be to uninstall pip, and then install with easy_install. Problem is, easy_install gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==36.5.0', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install-2.7')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2755, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2409, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2415, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    monkey.patch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/monkey.py", line 67, in patch_all
    distutils.core.Command = setuptools.Command
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

What's my next step? I'm trying to uninstall pip and reinstall it because pip itself was giving this same error.

Comment: what version of python 2.7 are you using? it should be already installed with 2.7.9+? (See [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6587507/1324033))

Comment: I'm using 2.7.14