# pip calls python from deleted virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I think I may have deleted a folder that contained a still-active virtualenv. Whenever I try to call pip, I get the error `/Users/me/bin/pip: /Users/me/VENV/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. The directory `VENV` no longer exists, but once contained a virtualenv.

I'm using MacOS 10.13, and have homebrew-installed versions of both Python and pip:

```
$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

which work fine. The problematic pip that's linked to the `pip` command lives at `/Users/me/bin/pip`. Since I'm unable to use it, I tried to just uninstall the problematic pip with `pip uninstall pip` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012597/how-to-uninstall-pip-on-osx-mavericks#29846144), but got the same error as before.

So I have two questions:

1. Does this seem like something that would happen if I deleted an active virtualenv?
2. How can I uninstall `/Users/me/bin/pip` from my system?

Comment: Is `/Users/me/bin/pip` here supposed to be `/Users/me/VENV/bin/pip`?  That would be consistent with having deleted an active virtualenv, the solution to which is to run `deactivate` and start over.

Comment: No, it's `/Users/me/bin/pip`. So it's calling what my guess is is the default macOS pip installation, but that in turn is trying to call a non-existent Python installation.