# Raspbian Buster - which Python version am I using?

Tags: python, version, raspbian

I am using the Raspberry Pi 4, running the latest version of Raspbian Buster. I am in the process of trying to update Python. Currently, when I run `python --version` in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Just out of curiosity, I tried to download a package that I need to use in the future to see where the install location would be. This is where it raised some concerns:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install simpleaudio
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting simpleaudio
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/simpleaudio/simpleaudio-1.0.4-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 3.1 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: simpleaudio
Successfully installed simpleaudio-1.0.4
```

When I try and install the package again (to see the install location):

```
Requirement already satisfied: simpleaudio in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.4)
```

I can see it has installed in this particular path. How can it be saved in Python 3.7 when I am running an older version? This was one of the first tests after a fresh install of Raspbian Buster. How does this work? Am I still technically running Python 2.7.16 or am I infact running Python 3.7?

Comment: What does `pip -V` print?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Answer (score 0):

On a freshly installed debian buster, I have `pip` and `pip3` (both version 18.1, but linked to Python2 or 3) available and also the pip-linked python versions with their commands `python` (version 2.7.16) and `python3` (version 3.7.3).

```
pip -V
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python2.7)
```

In a comment you've said that your `pip` command points to python3.7 - and that's why you're installing packages to python3 and not to python2. I think it is that simple.

So you probably need to install pip for python2 or simply create a virtual environment for your python2 packages.

If you prefer to use Python3 instead of Python2, not much has to be changed. It seems that you can just install your libraries with `pip install <library>` and then call your Python program(s) with `python3` (instead of `python` *(i.e. Python2)*). There you should find the libraries and be able to call them with `import <library name>`.

If you still have trouble to get `import` working, you can look if the site-packages path is in the search path of your interpreter:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

In the end, I guess it all comes from the fact that pip has no write permissions on site packages:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59997065/2648551). Maybe this is also helpful for you.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there any way I can solely use the newer version of Python(3.7) instad of Python2 and use import statements that point to this? Currently, when I use import it cannot find the package, which I assume is due to the fact that it is looking up the package in the wrong Python location.