# "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable" python message

Tags: python, installation, pip

Whenever I try to install a new python package I get this message first :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
```

even though I have administrator rights and I am running my `py` scripts and installation commands on my computer.

Any ideas why I keep getting this message before every and each `pip` installation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip/python: normal site-packages is not writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable)

Answer (score 5):

While this most likely is to be avoided, the only option I found to work is to use the --ignore-installed switch such as:

```
pip install -U --ignore-installed python-openstackclient
```

as root which allowed python to overwrite all old distro files with the correct new versions.

Comment: This fixed Jupyter Error "Running cells with 'Python 3.10.6 64-bit' requires notebook package." on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it mirrored my problem well. After running `python3 -m virtualenv myproject`, it created `myproject/local/bin/activate` instead of `myproject/bin/activate`, and after sourcing this file, `pip3 install some_package` would report **`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`** and proceed to install packages as the user rather than the virtual environment.

The fix for both issues was:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv
sudo apt install -y python3-virtualenv
```

This second command will be different for non-Debian distributions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who does not wanna reinstall python, if u get the defaulter message, then all you have to do is go to AppData>Roaming>Python>Python3.(X)>site-packages. Cut the folders that are related to the package(U can identify by seeing the date modified), and paste the folders in originally installed python.exe destination then>Lib>site-packages. Hopefully when you restart the code editor modules will work. I did this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy packages file to AppData>Roaming>Python>Python3.(X)>script directory

Comment: Seems like a repeat of part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954129/6243352), no?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I believe this issue was caused by a change in my $PATH. More specifically: another package which I recently installed superseded my pyenv shims directory and placed itself earlier than pyenv in the $PATH variable.

I am working with neuroimaging data, and the package in question is FSL. For reasons I would prefer not to contemplate, let alone understand, FSL installs a miniConda environment running python 3.11 in the chosen install directory, which I believe was being referenced first in my neuroimaging-poland ("nipl") environment, which runs python 3.9 via `pyenv`.

Further clues:

- I was noticing that packages I was trying to now install were version-matched to 3.11 instead of 3.9 (first clue)
- Packages I was certain were installed were not detected/listed by pip
- `which python` and `whereis python` were also pointing to the fsl directory instead of to my pyenv python.

***Moral of the story, for what might be a fringe case:***

- Make sure there are no python installs being referenced before the desired one, by going to your terminal and typing:

`echo $PATH`

- Confirm with `which python` or `Whereis python` as mentioned above.
- Moving pyenv initialization text to the bottom of my .zprofile file (which adds it last, but to the very FRONT of my $PATH variable) cleared up the error above.