# unable to install into conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, environment

is there a way to specify for a given python package to install in a given conda env vs. the User's python?

I thought that if I did `pip install <package>` in a given conda environment, this would make the package accessible in that environment.

If I create a conda environment and install [pySankey](https://pypi.org/project/pySankey/) then do `conda list`, pySankey won't show but instead be installed in `/Users/username/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/`

The package installs with "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable". I looked at other [stack posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable) associated with this, but I'm unclear how to modify ~/.bashrc, since my understanding is that ~/.bashrc is not unique to a conda environment. I also checked the path of the conda environment but there's no `local` as [indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808972/defaulting-to-user-installation-because-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable).

This has happened to me with a couple different packages (eg these packages do not pip install into the conda environment, other do), I'm using pySankey as an example.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error and realized that it was trying to use the system's pip instead of a conda pip.

Verify if your pip is either coming from a system directory (ie. /usr/bin/pip) or a conda directory:

```
which pip
```

Then fix by installing pip with conda:

```
conda install pip
```

and check again to verify (may need to activate a conda env first):

```
which pip
```

Comment: Thank you this worked to solve my issue `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`

By running `ocnda install pip` it did the following
```shell
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  setuptools         pkgs/main/linux-64::setuptools-68.2.2-py38h06a4308_0 

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates                     2023.12.12-h06a4308_0 --> 2024.3.11-h06a4308_0
```

I hope it will help other people.