# Azure Blob Storage tools not recognizable on M1 Mac in Python VENV

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, apple-m1

The only line in my code that references blob storage is a simple import statement, but when I uncomment it the entire function crashes. I can't seem to figure out how to get azure-storage-blob to be accessible by the VENV where the function is running.

I've already installed the requisite packages in terminal with Rosetta and am running VS Code with Rosetta as well. The Azure Functions core tools work, but the blob storage tools don't.

I've tried re-installing the package directly in the venv, incorporating the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable) to address the "normal site-packages is not writeable" error, but as shown I still get the same result:

```
(.venv) jonahrotholz@Jonahs-MacBook-Pro Azure w: Rosetta % python3 -m pip install azure-storage-blobDefaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Requirement already satisfied: azure-storage-blob in /Users/jonahrotholz/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (12.14.1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72369543/18359438) solve your issue?

Comment: Are you running the VS Code as an administrator mode for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue while working with Windows OS - Python Azure Functions.
But there are many reasons for this issue to occur with respective to User Installation of Python Packages, few of them with their resolutions.

In my previous workarounds, I always use to say to install Python Packages after activating the Virtual Environment and that seems not working in your case.

From the references SO #[65808972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808972/) and the [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-defaulting-to-user-installation-because-normal-site-packages-is-not-writable) given by the user @MingJie-MSFT and the author @BorislavHadzhiev, try with the below steps that will help to fix your issue and run the any of the below commands after activating the Virtual Environment:

1. `python -m pip install <Your_required_python_Package_Name>` - For Python Version 2
2. Replace the python word with `python3` or to a specific version `python3.x`
3. Append the parameter `--user` to python package installation command.
4. If all of the above not worked, then elevate the permissions by replacing the python installer commands like `python/python3.x` to `sudo pip`, `sudo pip3`, `sudo python`, `sudo python3`by running the Visual Studio Code IDE as an Administrator mode.
5. Check the Python interpreter is installed for all of the users or the current user with required permissions and check the python installed path is added to the Environment Variables in the System.