# Pip lists package as outdated but updating results in Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip

Solved using `sudo pip install -U <package>`

So when I do `pip list --outdated` I get:

```
Package           Version     Latest Type
----------------- ----------- ------ -----
anyio             3.3.3       3.3.4  wheel
cffi              1.14.6      1.15.0 wheel
contextlib2       0.6.0.post1 21.6.0 wheel
idna              3.2         3.3    wheel
ipywidgets        7.6.3       7.6.5  wheel
jsonschema        3.2.0       4.1.0  wheel
jupyter-client    6.1.12      7.0.6  wheel
keyring           23.0.1      23.2.1 wheel
matplotlib-inline 0.1.2       0.1.3  wheel
nbconvert         6.1.0       6.2.0  wheel
packaging         20.9        21.0   wheel
pandocfilters     1.4.3       1.5.0  wheel
pip               20.3.4      21.3   wheel
PyGObject         3.40.1      3.42.0 sdist
pyOpenSSL         20.0.1      21.0.0 wheel
pytz              2021.1      2021.3 wheel
pyzmq             22.2.1      22.3.0 wheel
resolvelib        0.5.5       0.8.1  wheel
setuptools        57.4.0      58.2.0 wheel
sip               4.19.25     6.3.1  wheel
terminado         0.11.1      0.12.1 wheel
trimesh           3.9.31      3.9.32 wheel
websocket-client  0.59.0      1.2.1  wheel
```

then when I do `pip install anyio -U` to update the first package I get:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: anyio in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from anyio) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio>=1.1 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from anyio) (1.2.0)
```

As I understand the package is already updated, but pip still lists the package as outdated and also doesn't list it in the updated package list.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable), and as you can guess the problem here is `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` which relates to some permission related issues which I am not sure of.

You can use here `python3 -m pip install -U <package>`.

> A stable solution could be to reinstall python from scratch in your system.

Comment: Didn't work. Also, how is `pip install -U anyio` different to `pip install anyio -U`.

Comment: use `python3 -m pip install -U anyio`, that should do it.  I would update the answer with proper reasons.

Comment: I guess my problem is not clear enough. I can update. When I do `pip install anyio -U` pip tells me that the package is already updated BUT when I do `pip list --outdated` the package still shows up on that list.

Comment: Yes, this is happening because `pip` is not updating your package in the site-packages and that's why when you do `pip list --outdated` it still shows up with a previous version. I have updated my answer with a link that addresses this behavior to more extent. You can read more there. Also, try using `python3 -m pip .....` command and then use `pip list --outdated` to see if it still shows up.

Comment: Depends on how you installed python. If it is installed with sudo, you might have to use it otherwise it may work fine by itself. I would suggest trying out both. Also, just an idea, what if you just used `sudo pip install anyio -U`, does that produces same effect or anything different(as I have mentioned this is a permission related issue).

Comment: Yes. `sudo pip install -U <package>` finally worked. Thank you.

Comment: Great, it was indeed a permission related issue.