# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 doesn't work on Windows

Tags: python, windows, trading, algorithmic-trading, metatrader5

I want to try MetaTrader5 programming with python,
in python file i have `import MetaTrader5`. But it's not possible to download that packages.
I tried to run this command on windows.

```
python -m pip install MetaTrader5
```

But it's just doesn't work. I tried to search internet. Everywhere is mention about MetaTrader5 doesn't work with python on linux, only on windows. But i'm trying it on Windows 11. Is there any way how to solve it?

I have python version 3.11

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check yout python version, MetaTrader5 only work with Python >= 3.5 and <4.

Check Doc
https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/

Comment: I have only one version of python installed. Latest 3.11

Comment: You can create a venv with python 3.5, take a look https://www.roelpeters.be/virtualenv-venv-choose-python-version/

Comment: if u dont know about venv look this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: Ok I understand but what is the logic behind it? 3.11 is between 3.5 and 4. So the version fits me. But thank you. I'll try version 3.5.

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, u also can upgrade your pip, and look about the other message that appear upside the python error "normal site-packages is not writeable", look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable

Comment: I'm on latest version with pip :( https://i.imgur.com/Y3cOeko.png

Comment: @ms_devel, looks like they don't support 3.11 yet. They ship only prebuilt wheels, no source distributions. So either downgrade your venv or wait. See https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/#files

Comment: @MaciejGol okey, so if i will install python 3.10 it will be working?

Comment: i use python 3.10 and that work

Comment: @MaciejGol working with 3.10.8, thanks!

Comment: close the question pls, happy to help!