# Can't see venv in the search window [Fresh install of Python and VS Code]

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, windows-11

I have been following the official instructions here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

In the code.visualstudio (VS) instructions, I don't see any sign of venv being built-in:

> Virtual environments
> A virtual environment is a built-in way to create an environment. A virtual environment creates a folder that contains a copy (or symlink) to a specific interpreter. When you install packages into a virtual environment it will end up in this new folder, and thus isolated from other packages used by other workspaces.

Note: While it's possible to open a virtual environment folder as a workspace, doing so is not recommended and might cause issues with using the Python extension.

When I get to this bit, nothing happens:

```
Using the Create Environment command
To create local environments in VS Code using virtual environments or Anaconda, you can follow these steps: open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), search for the Python: Create Environment command, and select it.

The command presents a list of environment types: Venv or Conda.

Create Environment dropdown

there's no venv (or conda) in the dropdown.

I tried installing via Windows Powershell, and this happens:

PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> pip install virtualenv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.25.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.7 (from virtualenv)
  Downloading distlib-0.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.12.2 (from virtualenv)
  Downloading filelock-3.13.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 (from virtualenv)
  Downloading platformdirs-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Downloading virtualenv-20.25.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.8/3.8 MB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading distlib-0.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 468.9/468.9 kB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading filelock-3.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Downloading platformdirs-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Installing collected packages: distlib, platformdirs, filelock, virtualenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed distlib-0.3.8 filelock-3.13.1 platformdirs-4.1.0 virtualenv-20.25.0
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> virtualenv --version
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> pip install virtualenv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (20.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (4.1.0)
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> virtualenv --version
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have added the path into path in Windows Environmental Variables, but it says it's not there.

I try to install it again, and it looks like it's still there... but it says it's not there.

```
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> pip install virtualenv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (20.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (4.1.0)
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects>
```

Any suggestions please?

It's not that I don't expect to have to configure anything, but I would have thought by now, a fresh install meant you got all the basics set up without getting drawn into endless demoralising roadblocks just to get set up.

Tried the stuff on here https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-defaulting-to-user-installation-because-normal-site-packages-is-not-writable
nothing...

e.g.:

```
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> python3.12 -m pip install venv
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement venv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for venv
```

on here: [pip/python: normal site-packages is not writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable)

this did create a "my-venv" in explorer...

```
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects> python -m venv my-venv
PS C:\Users\...\PythonProjects>
```

Comment: If the command pallet does not show you a drop down for "Python: Create Environment" then the first thing I would suggest is validating that you have the VSCode python extension installed.

Comment: I initially put "Python for VSCode" on, but it says its deprecated. There's a "vscode" one, and a few others with vscode in the title, which one do you recommend. I did see vscode on the explorer window. It's there now with settings.json under it, but I made a folder called .virtualenv and then the my-venv as mentioned above, and dragged the files I was working on under "include"... is it all supposed to be under vscode? I mean vscode was there in the explorer panel but still no venv coming up in the searchbar...

Comment: You want the VSCode Python extension from Microsoft. It is just called "python". See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: Yeah, I have that, but the specific "venv" thing does not appear. I do seem to be using virtual environment anyway. It's just not manifesting as in those official website guides. You'd think they verify the instructions they give with the versions for each thing.

Comment: For what it is worth, when I use the command pallet to create an environment, I get a dropdown of two items to pick between Venv and Conda.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to see, and I don't know why I didn't see it. I installed VS Code fresh, and python 3.9. Shortly after the installation of VS Community 2017/2022 finished, and then I installed Python 3.12 and uninstalled Python 3.9. Then what you see above...