# How to reset anaconda root environment

Tags: python, anaconda

How do I reset the root environment of anaconda? There has to be a simple conda reset command that does this.

I don't want to reinstall anaconda all over again. I have other virtualenvs that I don't want to overwrite and that will happen if I install anaconda again.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

See https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1032

> This has been implemented as `conda list --revisions` and `conda install --rev REV_NUM`.

EDIT: be careful though if you execute `conda install --rev 0` as this will remove your root environment and the `conda` command. Maybe `conda install --rev 1` would produce the desired behavior (restore root environment to its state after first installation).

EDIT 2018-03-07: Use the `--revision` argument instead of `--rev`

Comment: @bonobo I think this was a bug and I personally had to reinstall conda from scratch unfortunately (see [this conversation](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6290)). [A fix](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/6719) has apparently been merged earlier this year but I would still use this command with caution.

Comment: Note: this does not restore or remove packages installed with pip.

Comment: @mforbes haha so it does everything but what I actually want. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Note the output of `conda list --revisions` depends on what conda environment is currently active.

Comment: this link  https://www.shriramjaju.page/2018-05-30-2-minute-recipe-how-to-rollback-your-conda-environment/ explains clearly how to rollback anaconda to a previous state

Comment: @mforbes so to remove pip packages from conda base, could a nuke and reinstall of conda fix that, or would it still linger?

Comment: @mochsner It depends: if you use `pip install --user`, then `pip` will install everything in `site.USER_BASE` (usually `~/.local`) and these will persist, even if you reinstall conda.  However, if you don't use `--user`, then nuking conda should fix it.

Comment: @mforbes You could do pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze) as recommended here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip

Comment: Note: `conda install --revision 0` did not remove my root environment or remove conda.

Answer (score 11):

While this is not exactly what you are asking, I found `conda clean --all` useful to clean out a bunch of old packages, logs etc. which somewhat restores `conda` to a new state.

Comment: This answer is valuable and easy to implement. But it takes time to run, and I first thought my computer had flunked.

Answer (score 8):

I came to this post over and over again. Basically each time I inadvertently install packages into my base env. And each time do all the propose solutions which none works for me. What I end-up doing is re-install which is not too bad if you use linux / wsl

Backup existing installation

```
mv ~/miniconda3 ~/miniconda3_bck
```

get your the [installer](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/miniconda-other-installer-links.html) for the python version you had

```
miniconda_install_shell="https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh"
```

redo quick install as [official site recommends](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/)

```
mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
wget $miniconda_install_shell -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
rm ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
```

Restore your envs

```
mv ~/miniconda3_bck/envs ~/miniconda3
```

check if everthing works

```
conda info --envs
```

remove backup

```
rm ~/miniconda3_bck -rf
```

Yet I can't believe after all this time conda tean don't provide a way to lock the base env or at least ask for confirmation whenever the user try to install package in base env.

what I'm now doing is to remove write permission on my base env dir has explained detailed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51577325/14954327)

Comment: This looks bad initially but its actually a pretty easy, fast and good solution for this problem. Thanks

Comment: The dumbest thing is that after creating a new env it doesn't get activated automatically. So many times I run conda install right after that, and to my horror the base env gets a pile of junk!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Rolling back takes way too long, and if your base env has a broken solver you can't do it anyway.

Comment: This is was so fast. This _really_ should be the accepted answer since the accepted answer, as seen in the comments, only removes packages installed with conda (and not packages installed with pip).

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill but this worked for me when nothing else would. This is what is referred to as "nuking" in the above posts

Revert anaconda back to the install state

> conda install --rev 1

Uninstall all pip files

> pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)

remove all anaconda files

> rm -rf /Users/[username]/opt/anaconda3

reinstall from https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution

Update anaconda

> conda update conda

NOTE: Close your terminal between each step if you want to make sure you don't get "directory not found" errors

Comment: This `pip uninstall` business is a good way to break your currently installed anaconda, FYSA. :-)

Comment: Thats the goal though

Answer (score 0):

One might also consider `conda update anaconda` as a "nuclear option". The `anaconda` meta-package links together certain versions of packages that Continuum Analytics has figured out all play nice together.

Edit: As @mforbes points out, only do this if you are wanting to reset the base **anaconda** environment as distributed with the Anaconda (not Miniconda) installer. It has about 550 packages and is about a 1G download.

Comment: That's not resetting the environment at all, no?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... This approach doesn't reset the environment but it certainly makes it more consistent while still trying to keep it up to date... 
Given that lack of consistency is usually the main reason for looking after a full reset, then `conda update anaconda` could work as the least invasive first-aid approach, no?

Comment: My downvote was because I stumbled on this question when searching how to reset the base **conda** environment, for which the accepted answer is close to the answer.  Executing `conda update anaconda` would have installed the entire anaconda suite, completely the oposite of what I would have wanted and I did not want people to make this mistake.  However, since the OP did ask about **anaconda** specifically, perhaps this is reasonable.  If a a warning is included in the answer, I would remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
conda update --all
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```