# How to stop conda from copying installed packages to default pkgs directory?

Tags: windows, anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda3 on my Windows 10 laptop. I have two drives, C: and D:. Since C: is nearly full, I wanted to change the directory for the environments and packages over to D: which has much more storage. I changed the envs_dirs and pkgs_dirs in the conda config file to a folder I created for it on D:(lets say D:\myPackages for the pkgs) and made sure that those paths were at the top of the list. Then I created a new virtual environment and it got placed into the correct folder. But when I installed some python libraries, they were downloaded not only in the D:\myPackages directory but also into the standard \pkgs directory of conda.

How do I stop this, since I cant afford all the packages to be also copied on the C: drive. The D\myPackages path was the only one in pkgs_dirs so I am confused on why it did this.

I first followed this post to change the package directory: [Conda: Choose where packages are downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311208/conda-choose-where-packages-are-downloaded)

I did not find an adequate advise on stack overflow before asking the question, this post was said to result in more errors with conda: [Block package installations to conda base environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577258/block-package-installations-to-conda-base-environment)

Thanks in advance for reading my question!

Comment: look at the output of "conda info" and make sure the condarc you've changed is the one that shows as "user config file".

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-env-directories

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I did that and when I do "conda config --info" it shows the correctly edited pkgs_dirs