# ReadTimeoutError while installing tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I am getting below error while installing **tensorflow-gpu** from pip command.
Tried multiple attempts at different times assuming the network issue but the error remains persist.

```
(base) PS E:\...\coref-master> pip install tensorflow-gpu
    Collecting tensorflow-gpu
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/4c/87b658692746d66dfe687f3e0fe33ee58248f388961d2fdbc851b6c1d604/tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (356.5MB)
         |██                              | 25.6MB 25kB/s eta 3:39:40ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 397, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 479, in read
        data = self._fp.read(amt)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
        data = self.__fp.read(amt)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 457, in read
        n = self.readinto(b)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 501, in readinto
        n = self.fp.readinto(b)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 345, in run
        resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
        self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
        abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 307, in _get_abstract_dist_for
        self.require_hashes
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 199, in prepare_linked_requirement
        progress_bar=self.progress_bar
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1064, in unpack_url
        progress_bar=progress_bar
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 924, in unpack_http_url
        progress_bar)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1152, in _download_http_url
        _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 861, in _download_url
        hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py", line 75, in check_against_chunks
        for chunk in chunks:
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 829, in written_chunks
        for chunk in chunks:
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 156, in iter
        for x in it:
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 818, in resp_read
        decode_content=False):
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 531, in stream
        data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 496, in read
        raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 402, in _error_catcher
        raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
    pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

**Note:**

Already googled and tried different suggestions but no luck!

Comment: Be careful! Don't use the base/root environment, and don't use pip with Conda unless it's necessary and you're aware of the particularities that involves (see, for example, https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/). You might be able to reset the base environment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914139/how-to-reset-anaconda-root-environment), hopefully that will be enough, the alternative of course is to uninstall Conda and Anaconda completely and then reinstall them again.

Comment: Download the file with `curl` or `wget`, then install from local fs.

Comment: It's usually quite pointless to say "tried different suggestions". How would anyone know which ideas to exclude now? If you're going to mention something, give at least some idea what you actually tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip Install Timeout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305112/pip-install-timeout-issue)

Comment: You need to stay connected with internet while installing `tensorflow-gpu` in cmd using `!pip install tensorflow-gpu`.