# clean the base environment in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I was trying to install some libraries in a virtual environment.  By accident, I installed these libraries in the base environment instead of the targeted environment. Are there any ways to cleanup the environment in the base environment?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914139/how-to-reset-anaconda-root-environment

Comment: I agree with with the duplicate proposal, but more specifically for a recent rollback, look at `conda list --revisions`, then pick the most recent one before when you did the unintended install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a slick and safe one-liner to do this. You can uninstall things one-by-one, but that is tedious and risks accidentally uninstalling something you need. Having extra stuff installed in your base environment shouldn't be much of a problem; it's fine to just leave stuff there.