Removing Anaconda completely and starting over
I had many inconsistencies with two Anaconda environments that I had installed on my mac operating system, so I got advice on how to remove one of the environments and did so.
However, I think I would like to start from the beginning and remove the base environment. I tried to use anaconda-clean but because of a "setuptools" dependency of conda it cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed


RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.

I tried to use
rm -rf ~/anaconda3 

at the terminal but nothing appears to happen and when I check with
conda env list

it still shows that I have anaconda installed as a base environment
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3

How would I go about completely remove this and starting fresh?

I don't see what you think re-installing will do as far as "starting over" because of a bad environment. Remove the bad environment. You can reset your base environment as well, if you want to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830307/conda-remove-all-installed-packages-from-base-root-environment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914139/how-to-reset-anaconda-root-environment

But if you do wish to uninstall ... I would suggest first follow the docs instructions: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/
