# ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I moved this app from Windows to Mac. It was working fine on windows.
After that I ran `pip install -t lib requirements.txt`
And now getting this error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sa/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/sa/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/sa/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/sa/Documents/GitHub/ga/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from importer import import_report_data, generate_csv
  File "/Users/sa/Documents/GitHub/ga/importer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import bq_client
  File "/Users/sa/Documents/GitHub/ga/bq_client.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.cloud import bigquery
  File "/Users/sa/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 1061, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery`

So, I did `pip install -t lib --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery` and got below error

`Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 423, in run
    shutil.rmtree(target_item_dir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/sa/Documents/GitHub/ga/lib/cachetools/__init__.py'`

Then used `sudo pip install -t lib --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`. The install was successful but I get the same original error again. `No module named google.cloud.bigquery`

Comment: all sorts of errors I am getting now. It seems to me that I have somehow messed up my python version when i migrated windows app and installed the packages from requirements.txt that was frozen on windows. Is there any way to clean up all python packages and have a fresh start

Comment: how many python versions do you have installed, and what is your default set to e.g run `python` and look at the version.

Comment: Perhaps try to [delete all your pip packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250821/516942) and try installation again?

Comment: I suspect you have 3.x installed too, and that's where pip is installing. Try installing to a specific version - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions

Comment: I only have Python 2.7 installed. @VictorMota getting error . while deleting packages OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.12.2.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'