# Operation not permitted error when trying to do pip uninstall. How to resolve it?

Tags: python-2.7

OS: macOS Sierra

Python 2.7.10

I am trying to cleanup all python libraries. I am trying to do this while trying to resolve another issue mentioned here [ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530919/importerror-no-module-named-google-cloud-bigquery)

`$ sudo pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
The directory '/Users/sa/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Uninstalling altgraph-0.10.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph', '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/br/cmwb0g0109n9f6sb268gfh75g1kljc/T/pip-Qvf8FD-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph'")]`

Comment: You probably have to use `sudo`?

Comment: Updated the question. @a_guest now getting different error.

Comment: You probably need to use `sudo pip freeze | xargs sudo pip uninstall -y`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems that there are issues using the pip that comes with MacOS.

Instead of uninstalling, you can install the latest versions of Python packages into your own home directory with the --user flag. See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site

pip install  --user