# "pip freeze" shows extra packages too?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to do a `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt`. I'm running this in a virtualenv. However, even with the `-l` option, `pip freeze` gives me a list of *all* the packages installed in my system, which is a huge and unnecessarily long list. All I need are Flask and a few other libraries, but this is the list it gives me:

```
altgraph (0.10.2)
bdist-mpkg (0.5.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.5.3)
bonjour-py (0.3)
cachetools (2.0.1)
certifi (2017.7.27.1)
chardet (3.0.4)
click (6.7)
Flask (0.12.1)
futures (3.1.1)
google (1.9.3)
google-api-python-client (1.6.4)
google-auth (1.2.0)
google-auth-httplib2 (0.0.2)
google-auth-oauthlib (0.1.1)
gunicorn (19.7.1)
httplib2 (0.10.3)
idna (2.6)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.9.6)
macholib (1.5.1)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
modulegraph (0.10.4)
numpy (1.12.1)
oauth2client (4.1.2)
oauthlib (2.0.6)
pbr (2.0.0)
pip (9.0.1)
psycopg2 (2.7.3.2)
py2app (0.7.3)
pyasn1 (0.3.7)
pyasn1-modules (0.1.5)
pyobjc-core (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Accounts (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Automator (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreData (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreText (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-EventKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Message (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PubSub (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-QTKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Quartz (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Social (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-WebKit (2.5.1)
pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
python-dateutil (1.5)
pytz (2013.7)
requests (2.18.4)
requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
rsa (3.4.2)
scipy (0.13.0b1)
setuptools (18.5)
SimpleCV (1.3)
six (1.11.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.1.15)
stevedore (1.21.0)
uritemplate (3.0.0)
urllib3 (1.22)
vboxapi (1.0)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.6)
virtualenvwrapper (4.7.2)
Werkzeug (0.12.1)
wheel (0.30.0)
xattr (0.6.4)
zope.interface (4.1.1)
```

I have tried trouble-shooting this so that `pip freeze -l` shows only the packages *in my current virtualenv root*. **Here is what hasn't worked so far:**

1. Resetting the virtualenv using either `virtualenv --clear venv` or `virtualenv --no-site-packages venv`.
2. Trying to uninstall all local packages using `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` [found at this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip). I got the `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted` error because for some reason even though I'm in the virtualenv it tried uninstalling the packages from the OS X root.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the result of `pip freeze --local` any different to `pip freeze`?  If so, how?

Comment: Not at all, actually.

Comment: What about `pip freeze --user`?  That's the only other option that appears potentially relevant.

Comment: There seem to be no packages matching that, because it shows not a single line of output.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you activate your virtualenv before `pip freeze`?

Comment: Yeah of course haha @bgse

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was not using sudo.

```
sudo pipenv clean
```