# How to change Python version of existing conda virtual environment?

Tags: python, version, conda, virtual-environment

I created a conda environment with Python version 3.8, but it doesn't support matplotlib... So I am looking for something like this to change the Python version: `conda env my_env update to python=3.6`. Is this possible or do I need to recreate the environment?

I have miniconda installed.

Comment: Thx for this question. Got an UnsatisfiableError on CUDA driver when I tried to install keras in a conda env with python 3.8. Changing to python v. 3.7 solved the issue.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Activate the relevant environment, then install your target python version.

```
conda activate my_env
conda install python=3.6
```

Comment: Omg, it's so obvious... My only excuse is that I'm completely new to it. Thank you!

Comment: I did this but still the version doesn't change

Comment: @B.Quaink That sounds very unlikely. If true, please create a new post providing the exact steps you took  (including OS) and then link back.

Comment: I created a new environment and then set up the python version, that worked. Maybe the base(root) environment isn't changeable? I followed your steps above, it said it changed but when I started up python the newer version was still there.

Comment: Yes, the base environment is based on the conda version downloaded. You first need to create a new environment before you can install another version of python into it.

Comment: Restart your shell if the version does not change after doing this.

Comment: I had to ```conda uninstall python``` then I could install a new version. Otherwise the version did not change for me.

Comment: Might need to uninstall the current python and then install the desired one... otherwise, you might get conflicts for some packages which are dependent to the current python.

Comment: are you sure this works? I run python and it still says 3.8.2...

Comment: @Alexander can you try 3.9? Perhaps that is the issue `conda install python=3.9`

Comment: @Alexander what does the `-n base` flag do?

Comment: why would `conda update conda` not be enough? (perhaps this is my issue)

Comment: Everytime I update python, then I find myself in conda-conflict-hell after which point you have to steadily delete packages until the install finally works and then you can reinstall. I've had the most success by first removing python_abi and then some graphics packages, e.g. remove "xz" and it'll knock out a lot.

Comment: What happens with the installed packages that explicitly rely on the previous Python version binaries?

Comment: @Ataxias The safest thing to do is create a new environment with the target python version and then install the required packages.

Answer (score 33):

Adding to the answer above

```
conda activate my_env
conda uninstall python
conda install python=x.x
```

Comment: Any explanation for uninstall and reinstall python instead of just upgrade it?

Comment: Not in particular, the existing solution didn't work for me and this did so felt like sharing :). I would imagine upgrade would work too

Comment: This caused me to lose all my packages, might as well create a new environment

Comment: @JeffBezos Some preliminary research suggests that should not be the case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip#:~:text=%40patelshahrukh%20uninstalling%20python%20DOES%20NOT,that's%20more%20work%20to%20fix. I will test it though - if it does I will update the answer to make people aware.

Answer (score 6):

Rebuild a new environment, for example called "myenvi"

```py
conda create --name myenvi python=3.6
```

And make sure the version by

```py
python --version
```

After installing all packages, double-check with

```py
conda list -n myenvi
```

Comment: While your way solves the problem, the OP asked for a way that would allow them to keep the existing environment. So, this answer does not really help here.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have existing python installation may be in other environment, you can simply use it as base.

Here's what you need to do:

```cs
conda activate base
conda install python=3.6
```

Note: This will activate root environment. and python 3.6 already installed, it will simply replace it.