# Updating python in anaconda virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I am trying to update my python version in an anaconda3 virtual environment from 3.6 to 3.10.

**Steps taken:**

**1**. Download python 3.10 64bit from pyton.org

**2.** anaconda prompt: `conda activate gis` (my venv)

**3.** anaconda prompt: `(gis) C:\User\User>python -m venv --upgrade "C:/Users/User/anaconda3/envs/gis"` (path to my virtual environment)

**4.** check python version in venv: **did not change, still 3.6.**

note: command prompt displays `Python was not found` when passed `python --version` which is inconsistent with tutorials I have watched. I thought that because I was using anaconda, possibly I was to follow the same steps as the tutorials but in anaconda prompt. Maybe this was an incorrect assumption.

If I check the version in my `base` environment, it is 3.10. This happened automatically upon downloading python 3.10.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "1. Download python 3.10 64bit from pyton.org" **no**. Don't do that, use `conda`

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163078/how-to-change-python-version-of-existing-conda-virtual-environment

Comment: But as noted, it is probably better just to create a new environment starting from Python 3.10 and installing your dependencies from the old environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up `venv` and `conda`. Your environment is managed by `conda` (which is a project separate from the Python language), whereas `venv` is the de facto virtual environment manager used within the Python language. I'm not even sure how `venv` handles the command you have provided.

If having 3.10 is a priority, I would suggest that you create a new `conda` environment using `3.10` and [install any packages from your previous `3.6` environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file). (This is also [what the conda project recommends](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python).)

Comment: ahah thanks for clearing that up a bit. Hmm yes, and attempting to update python using `conda update python` produced all kinds of conflicts hence why they suggest creating a new envrionment eh? I think that is how I will try to move forward.