# ERROR: No matching distribution found for typed-json-dataclass

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-dataclasses, requirements.txt

Goal: install `typed-json-dataclass` in `project` venv.

- Python 3.6.13
- conda 4.11.0

Terminal:

```bash
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ pip install typed_json_dataclass
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typed_json_dataclass (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typed_json_dataclass
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ pip install typed-json-dataclass
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typed-json-dataclass (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typed-json-dataclass
```

---

`requirements.txt`:

```
typed_json_dataclass
typed_json_dataclass==1.2.1
typed_json_dataclass==1.2.*
```

Terminal:

```bash
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typed_json_dataclass (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typed_json_dataclass
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typed_json_dataclass==1.2.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typed_json_dataclass==1.2.1
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typed_json_dataclass==1.2.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typed_json_dataclass==1.2.*
```

---

I can however install via. a separate project repo and venv:

- Python 3.9.12

Terminal:

```bash
(project2) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project2$ pip install typed_json_dataclass
Requirement already satisfied: typed_json_dataclass in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8-tuple<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from typed_json_dataclass) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8-tuple<0.5.0,>=0.4.0->typed_json_dataclass) (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8-tuple<0.5.0,>=0.4.0->typed_json_dataclass) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes<2.5.0,>=2.4.0 in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8->flake8-tuple<0.5.0,>=0.4.0->typed_json_dataclass) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8->flake8-tuple<0.5.0,>=0.4.0->typed_json_dataclass) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.9.0,>=2.8.0 in /home/me/miniconda3/envs/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8->flake8-tuple<0.5.0,>=0.4.0->typed_json_dataclass) (2.8.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the pypi page of typed-json-dataclass](https://pypi.org/project/typed-json-dataclass/#description) under **Meta**:

> Requires: Python >=3.7, <4.0

which is why `pip` cannot install it for your python 3.6

There is no way to get it to work with python 3.6, as its sole purpose is to expand the [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) which was only added in python 3.7, so you will need to switch to a different python version (if possible)

Comment: `conda install python=3.7` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59163125/16852041)