# How to install all the dependencies with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have a NodeJS API and a Python script. I deployed it on Heroku. The API call runs the python scripts.

When I deployed the NodeJS API then type `npm install` and all works fine but not for python. There is a lot of pip package to install, how can I make this work same as in my local environment?

In short, what is the "One command to install them all"?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt` . If you do not have a `requirements.txt` - you can create one using `pip freeze`.

Comment: "requirements.txt" creating automaticly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your requirements in a requirements.txt file and then

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

will install all at the same time.

You can create it by

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

but should include only the packages you really use.

Comment: The txt file, how it will looks like
pandas
numpy ...

or

Comment: each line contain the package name and the version your project depend on
it's the same output as pip freeze (since pip freeze > requirements.txt; create the file requirements.txt from the pip freeze output)

Comment: "pip freeze > requirements.txt" okay then it works fine really. Just one more think I want to reset all my packages or should I say clean the pip installed packages.I am using anaconda in my local desktop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip

Comment: Okay I saw that but I did'nt understand until now the requirements.txt..Thank all of you

Comment: One last question, It gives a lot of error. It installs some packages but some of them with red big error.Is this because anaconda spyder

Comment: what kind of errors ? can you paste it here or create a new questions ?