# Why is Jupyter Lab taking a long time to load and freezing, and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-lab

I have reinstalled Python and recreated my (venv) virtual environment multiple times, as well as followed suggestions on [my first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344847/how-can-i-do-a-fresh-installation-of-python-and-jupyter-lab) on this issue. However I am getting the same results: Jupyter Lab launches but is slow, and sometimes the notebook won't even load. If the notebook does load, doing anything inside causes it to freeze. Another odd point I don't understand is how it knows of previous extensions from other environments that have been removed (perhaps a config file somewhere).

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Windows 10

Python 3.8.5

Jupyter Lab 2.2.8

Below is my output of launching, with debug on.

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\griffitb\OneDrive - HP Inc\SIE\NewEnv> jupyter lab --debug
[D 09:14:44.748 LabApp] Searching ['C:\\Users\\griffitb\\OneDrive - HP Inc\\SIE\\NewEnv', 'C:\\Users\\griffitb\\.jupyter', 'c:\\users\\griffitb\\onedrive - hp inc\\sie\\newenv\\.venv\\etc\\jupyter', 'C:\\ProgramData\\jupyter'] for config files
[D 09:14:44.749 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 09:14:44.749 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\etc\jupyter
[D 09:14:44.749 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\griffitb\.jupyter
[D 09:14:44.750 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\griffitb\OneDrive - HP Inc\SIE\NewEnv
[D 09:14:44.751 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 09:14:44.752 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\etc\jupyter
[D 09:14:44.752 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\griffitb\.jupyter
[D 09:14:44.753 LabApp] Loaded config file: C:\Users\griffitb\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 09:14:44.754 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\griffitb\OneDrive - HP Inc\SIE\NewEnv
[D 09:14:44.755 LabApp] Ignoring min_open_files_limit because the limit cannot be adjusted (for example, on Windows)
[D 09:14:44.761 LabApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
        C:\ProgramData\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 09:14:44.762 LabApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
        c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.d\jupyterlab.json
        c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 09:14:44.765 LabApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config:
        C:\Users\griffitb\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[W 09:14:45.236 LabApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')
[I 09:14:45.619 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 09:14:45.620 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\lab
[W 09:14:45.623 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab_code_formatter
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1942, in init_server_extensions
        mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
      File "C:\Users\griffitb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab_code_formatter'
[I 09:14:45.625 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\griffitb\OneDrive - HP Inc\SIE\NewEnv
[I 09:14:45.625 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 09:14:45.626 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7a41dc514e42ae156090b3872efc947143593ef0c4c01c15
[I 09:14:45.626 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7a41dc514e42ae156090b3872efc947143593ef0c4c01c15
[I 09:14:45.626 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:14:45.735 LabApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/griffitb/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-64976-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7a41dc514e42ae156090b3872efc947143593ef0c4c01c15
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7a41dc514e42ae156090b3872efc947143593ef0c4c01c15
[D 09:14:47.313 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:47.316 LabApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 09:14:47.323 LabApp] 200 GET /lab?token=7a41dc514e42ae156090b3872efc947143593ef0c4c01c15 (::1) 10.97ms
[D 09:14:47.363 LabApp] Path main.96d5afda0af51b39975b.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\lab\static\main.96d5afda0af51b39975b.js
[D 09:14:47.365 LabApp] 304 GET /static/lab/main.96d5afda0af51b39975b.js (::1) 2.99ms
[D 09:14:47.367 LabApp] Path vendors~main.51cd9a4c9968962f7d0f.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\lab\static\vendors~main.51cd9a4c9968962f7d0f.js
[D 09:14:47.368 LabApp] 304 GET /static/lab/vendors~main.51cd9a4c9968962f7d0f.js (::1) 2.00ms
[D 09:14:47.741 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:47.744 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 09:14:47.754 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1602692087737 (::1) 12.97ms
[D 09:14:47.755 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:47.862 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/?1602692087741 (::1) 106.75ms
[D 09:14:47.864 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:47.866 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:47.867 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:47.869 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1602692087769 (::1) 4.95ms
[D 09:14:47.871 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 09:14:47.874 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1602692087805 (::1) 7.98ms
[D 09:14:47.875 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernels?1602692087768 (::1) 7.98ms
[D 09:14:47.997 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:48.000 LabApp] 200 GET /metrics?1602692087993 (::1) 3.99ms
[D 09:14:48.005 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:48.024 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:48.195 LabApp] Node v12.18.4

[D 09:14:48.753 LabApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[D 09:14:49.060 LabApp] 200 GET /api/nbconvert?1602692088020 (::1) 1035.45ms
[I 09:14:49.062 LabApp] Build is up to date
[D 09:14:49.063 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.064 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.065 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.065 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/build?1602692087999 (::1) 1060.42ms
[D 09:14:49.068 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:plugin?1602692088311 (::1) 4.98ms
[D 09:14:49.070 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/listings/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension/listings.json?1602692088200 (::1) 5.98ms
[D 09:14:49.073 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/workspaces/lab?1602692088227 (::1) 7.94ms
[D 09:14:49.074 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.075 LabApp] Path @jupyterlab\theme-dark-extension\index.css served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-dark-extension\index.css
[D 09:14:49.076 LabApp] 304 GET /lab/api/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css (::1) 6.98ms
[D 09:14:49.756 LabApp] 200 GET /api/nbconvert?1602692088052 (::1) 682.55ms
[D 09:14:49.757 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.757 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.758 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.760 LabApp] 204 PUT /lab/api/workspaces/lab?1602692089592 (::1) 4.01ms
[D 09:14:49.761 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:49.765 LabApp] 200 GET /metrics?1602692089527 (::1) 8.01ms
[D 09:14:49.766 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb?content=0&1602692089091 (::1) 7.98ms
[D 09:14:50.179 LabApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[D 09:14:50.182 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/extensions?1602692089087 (::1) 421.16ms
[D 09:14:50.183 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:50.184 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:50.185 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:50.192 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1602692089902 (::1) 7.98ms
[W 09:14:51.855 LabApp] Notebook M1P1 Feature_v0p1.ipynb is not trusted
[D 09:14:52.613 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb?type=notebook&content=1&1602692089895 (::1) 2428.06ms
[D 09:14:52.701 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/?1602692089892 (::1) 2515.33ms
[D 09:14:52.702 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:52.711 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:14:52.720 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/extensions?1602692090090 (::1) 17.98ms
[D 09:14:52.723 LabApp] 204 PUT /lab/api/workspaces/lab?1602692090416 (::1) 11.97ms
[D 09:14:53.208 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\MathJax.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\MathJax.js
[D 09:14:53.210 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe&amp;delayStartupUntil=configured (::1) 2.99ms
[D 09:15:38.648 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:38.651 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb/checkpoints?1602692138642 (::1) 3.99ms
[D 09:15:38.652 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:38.655 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb/checkpoints?1602692138643 (::1) 3.99ms
[D 09:15:38.841 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:38.843 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb/checkpoints?1602692138837 (::1) 1.99ms
[D 09:15:40.295 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.302 LabApp] 200 GET /metrics?1602692140229 (::1) 7.98ms
[D 09:15:40.319 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.320 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.320 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.321 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.322 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\config\TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\config\TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js
[D 09:15:40.323 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 5.99ms
[D 09:15:40.327 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1602692140232 (::1) 8.97ms
[D 09:15:40.329 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernels?1602692140231 (::1) 9.97ms
[D 09:15:40.330 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1602692140267 (::1) 9.95ms
[D 09:15:40.331 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1602692140230 (::1) 9.95ms
[D 09:15:40.341 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.490 LabApp] Starting kernel: ['c:\\users\\griffitb\\onedrive - hp inc\\sie\\newenv\\.venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\griffitb\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113.json']
[D 09:15:40.505 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55223
[D 09:15:40.513 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55220
[I 09:15:40.518 LabApp] Kernel started: 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113, name: python3
[D 09:15:40.518 LabApp] Kernel args: {'kernel_name': 'python3', 'cwd': 'C:\\Users\\griffitb\\OneDrive - HP Inc\\SIE\\NewEnv'}
[D 09:15:40.520 LabApp] 201 POST /api/sessions?1602692140337 (::1) 179.52ms
[D 09:15:40.521 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\config\Safe.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\config\Safe.js
[D 09:15:40.523 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/Safe.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 1.99ms
[D 09:15:40.532 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.533 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1602692140524 (::1) 1.00ms
[D 09:15:40.557 LabApp] Initializing websocket connection /api/kernels/3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113/channels
[D 09:15:40.559 LabApp] Requesting kernel info from 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113
[D 09:15:40.559 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55219
[D 09:15:40.564 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.565 LabApp] 200 PATCH /api/sessions/d852c8ea-2ae0-4447-ad89-2ee044cce50b?1602692140559 (::1) 1.00ms
[D 09:15:40.569 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:15:40.571 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernels?1602692140566 (::1) 2.00ms
[D 09:15:40.586 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\extensions\Safe.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\extensions\Safe.js
[D 09:15:40.587 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/extensions/Safe.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 1.99ms
[D 09:15:40.862 LabApp] Initializing websocket connection /api/kernels/3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113/channels
[D 09:15:40.864 LabApp] Waiting for pending kernel_info request
[D 09:15:42.263 LabApp] activity on 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113: status (busy)
[D 09:15:42.264 LabApp] activity on 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113: status (idle)
[D 09:15:42.264 LabApp] Received kernel info: {'status': 'ok', 'protocol_version': '5.3', 'implementation': 'ipython', 'implementation_version': '7.18.1', 'language_info': {'name': 'python', 'version': '3.8.5', 'mimetype': 'text/x-python', 'codemirror_mode': {'name': 'ipython', 'version': 3}, 'pygments_lexer': 'ipython3', 'nbconvert_exporter': 'python', 'file_extension': '.py'}, 'banner': "Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]\nType 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information\nIPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.\n", 'help_links': [{'text': 'Python Reference', 'url': 'https://docs.python.org/3.8'}, {'text': 'IPython Reference', 'url': 'https://ipython.org/documentation.html'}, {'text': 'NumPy Reference', 'url': 'https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/'}, {'text': 'SciPy Reference', 'url': 'https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/'}, {'text': 'Matplotlib Reference', 'url': 'https://matplotlib.org/contents.html'}, {'text': 'SymPy Reference', 'url': 'http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html'}, {'text': 'pandas Reference', 'url': 'https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/'}]}
[D 09:15:42.266 LabApp] 101 GET /api/kernels/3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113/channels?session_id=6fae3452-4853-4dc7-8a43-35ee26bc8eb8 (::1) 1709.31ms
[D 09:15:42.267 LabApp] Opening websocket /api/kernels/3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113/channels
[D 09:15:42.267 LabApp] Getting buffer for 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113
[D 09:15:42.267 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55219
[D 09:15:42.270 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55223
[D 09:15:42.272 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55220
[D 09:15:42.276 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55221
[D 09:15:42.279 LabApp] 101 GET /api/kernels/3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113/channels?session_id=7bafe641-c1b0-4c6e-9aee-3b2c07a4eebc (127.0.0.1) 1417.00ms
[D 09:15:42.279 LabApp] Opening websocket /api/kernels/3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113/channels
[D 09:15:42.280 LabApp] Getting buffer for 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113
[D 09:15:42.282 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55219
[D 09:15:42.294 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55223
[D 09:15:42.298 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55220
[D 09:15:42.301 LabApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55221
[D 09:15:45.959 LabApp] Websocket closed 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113:7bafe641-c1b0-4c6e-9aee-3b2c07a4eebc
[D 09:15:45.961 LabApp] Websocket closed 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113:6fae3452-4853-4dc7-8a43-35ee26bc8eb8
[I 09:15:45.962 LabApp] Starting buffering for 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113:6fae3452-4853-4dc7-8a43-35ee26bc8eb8
[D 09:15:45.962 LabApp] Clearing buffer for 3dc3f1fb-0a8b-494c-b7a9-9472e0faf113
[D 09:20:04.402 LabApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 09:20:04.411 LabApp] 200 GET /lab (::1) 9.97ms
[D 09:20:04.456 LabApp] 304 GET /static/lab/main.96d5afda0af51b39975b.js (::1) 3.00ms
[D 09:20:04.460 LabApp] 304 GET /static/lab/vendors~main.51cd9a4c9968962f7d0f.js (::1) 2.00ms
[D 09:20:04.908 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:04.909 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 09:20:04.912 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1602692404904 (::1) 2.99ms
[D 09:20:04.913 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:04.993 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/?1602692404908 (::1) 81.81ms
[D 09:20:04.994 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:04.995 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:04.996 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:04.997 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernels?1602692404932 (::1) 3.04ms
[D 09:20:04.998 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 09:20:04.999 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1602692404974 (::1) 3.99ms
[D 09:20:05.000 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1602692404933 (::1) 3.90ms
[D 09:20:05.101 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.107 LabApp] 200 GET /metrics?1602692405098 (::1) 4.99ms
[D 09:20:05.124 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.136 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.270 LabApp] Node v12.18.4

[D 09:20:05.712 LabApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[D 09:20:05.869 LabApp] 200 GET /api/nbconvert?1602692405133 (::1) 732.43ms
[I 09:20:05.870 LabApp] Build is up to date
[D 09:20:05.871 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.872 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/build?1602692405120 (::1) 748.39ms
[D 09:20:05.875 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:plugin?1602692405393 (::1) 3.99ms
[D 09:20:05.876 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.878 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.879 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:05.880 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/listings/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension/listings.json?1602692405305 (::1) 3.99ms
[D 09:20:05.882 LabApp] 304 GET /lab/api/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css (::1) 4.99ms
[D 09:20:05.884 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/workspaces/lab?1602692405328 (::1) 5.98ms
[D 09:20:06.571 LabApp] 200 GET /api/nbconvert?1602692405156 (::1) 691.73ms
[D 09:20:06.572 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:06.574 LabApp] 204 PUT /lab/api/workspaces/lab?1602692406459 (::1) 2.99ms
[D 09:20:06.575 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:06.577 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:06.577 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:06.582 LabApp] 200 GET /metrics?1602692406005 (::1) 7.01ms
[D 09:20:06.583 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb?content=0&1602692405959 (::1) 6.98ms
[D 09:20:06.590 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/extensions?1602692405952 (::1) 12.97ms
[D 09:20:06.685 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:06.758 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/?1602692406681 (::1) 73.80ms
[D 09:20:06.760 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:06.760 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 09:20:08.316 LabApp] Notebook M1P1 Feature_v0p1.ipynb is not trusted
[D 09:20:09.062 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb?type=notebook&content=1&1602692406685 (::1) 2303.19ms
[D 09:20:09.077 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1602692406692 (::1) 2317.19ms
[D 09:20:09.085 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:09.086 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:09.094 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/extensions?1602692406955 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 09:20:09.096 LabApp] 204 PUT /lab/api/workspaces/lab?1602692407203 (::1) 9.97ms
[D 09:20:09.564 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe&amp;delayStartupUntil=configured (::1) 1.00ms
[D 09:20:55.123 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:55.126 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb/checkpoints?1602692455119 (::1) 2.99ms
[D 09:20:55.126 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:55.128 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb/checkpoints?1602692455120 (::1) 1.99ms
[D 09:20:55.284 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 09:20:55.286 LabApp] 200 GET /api/contents/M1P1%20Feature_v0p1.ipynb/checkpoints?1602692455282 (::1) 1.99ms
[D 09:20:56.719 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 1.00ms
[D 09:20:56.742 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/Safe.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 1.00ms
[D 09:20:58.520 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/extensions/Safe.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 1.00ms
[D 09:20:59.518 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\jax\output\HTML-CSS\fonts\STIX-Web\fontdata.js served from c:\users\griffitb\onedrive - hp inc\sie\newenv\.venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\jax\output\HTML-CSS\fonts\STIX-Web\fontdata.js
[D 09:20:59.519 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX-Web/fontdata.js?V=2.7.9 (::1) 1.99ms
```

Comment: Potentially check the difference between the first and second loading. JupyterHub is a crazily heavy web application and first request might last long (10 minutes in case of some local tunneling). However, for the second use, the session might be cashed and works pretty smoothly. I can confirm a near-localhost experience. Thus, try it once, wait and hope for future use it will be okay. If you log as another user, it might last long. But only once.