# Reinstall uninstalled packages

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I just followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip) in order to clean up my directory of old pip installations, having just reinstalled a fresh version of Anaconda3. However, I realised that this might have messed things up and I'd like to reinstall all of the packages. When I try `pip install` on all the packages I uninstalled, for some I get errors now:

```
(base) Dhruvss-MBP:~ dhruv$ pip install atomicwrites
Collecting atomicwrites
  Downloading atomicwrites-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Installing collected packages: atomicwrites
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 4.2.5 requires applaunchservices>=0.1.7; platform_system == "Darwin", which is not installed.
spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, which is not installed.
spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.
```

I also noticed I have a `requirements.txt` file in my home directory which does indeed have lots of the old packages I uninstalled (no idea how this file retained those). When I try and reinstall from that file it also throws an error:

*requirements.txt*

```
alabaster @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/alabaster_1611921544520/work
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==2.0.3
anaconda-project @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/anaconda-project_1610472525955/work
anyio @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/64740ac7-3a9c-4fbb-6685-a51c4ff8b4ca/volume/anyio_1617783319350/work/dist
appdirs==1.4.4
applaunchservices==0.2.1
...
```

*error on command line*

```
(base) Dhruvss-MBP:~ dhruv$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Processing /home/ktietz/src/ci/alabaster_1611921544520/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ktietz/src/ci/alabaster_1611921544520/work'
```

**Any idea how I can somehow install these again and get a fresh install?**

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is that there is `@ file...` lines in your `requirements.txt`, which refer to files on your computer you might have thrown away.

- You can check your bin for deleted files.
- You can remove those lines if you don't need those packages.