# removing pip packages from anaconda base env

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I've recently read about the dangers of using pip to install packages in an environment. Unfortunately, before I learned this I had already installed packages with pip in my base environment. From what I've read, the --revision command option doesn't remove the pip packages, just those installed via conda. Is this anyway to correct this mess short of a complete reinstall? No doubt complicating matters, I don't have a list of what I installed with pip.

Comment: When you do `conda list` all pip installed packages should show with channel and build `pypi`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250821/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+uninstall+all+packages

Comment: @phd that solution does not work in this case, as `pip freeze` will also list conda installed packages

Comment: @FlyingTeller - this lists a few packages, which may cover all those for which I called pip install. However, these installs typically invoked a possibly large number of dependencies and these don't seem to get removed. Do these remaining dependencies create the same sort of env corruption that the pip installed packages do?  If I go ahead with a clean reinstall, can I preserve any parts of my Navigator or Spyder state?

Comment: Please ping me if you disagree with the duplicate, but the answer there gives a command for removing all PyPI packages from a Conda environment.

Comment: thanks for the link to the complete answer.