# Remove all pip packages

Tags: linux, pip, manjaro

I'm using Linux/Manjaro KDE.

Since I was not familiar with Venv I installed more than 50 packages in my global and not everything is conflicted.
In order to clean up all pip packages I tried this command:

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall
```

and even this one:

```
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
python -m pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

In both cases I get this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'apparmor'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

and then the progress will be interrupted.
Any solution?

Comment: Try deleting the packages that are giving you the errors manually. If you're root you will find them here `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/`; Else you can find them here `/home/normaluser/.local/lib..`

Comment: I also suggest you to look at this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip

Comment: @Enrico Manjaro is using some packages for itself and I think if you do that you will get some OS issues with Manjaro.
Already saw the link you posted, couldn't solve the problem

Comment: hmm got it, since you're using a virtual enviroment, did you try this? `virtualenv --clear MYENV`

Comment: Read the question again @Enrico :) I didn't use virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could remove everything like this:
To get room permissions:

```
sudo su
```

and then removed anything on this location:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).