# pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10 not supported in python 3.8.2 version

Tags: python

pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10 this package not installed in python 3.8.2 version.so when I run the gaming project so that time this error showing.instead of this I am install pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev12,this package is install but same error is showing.
so can anyone give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

As I know PyGame is support for python 3

You can try this:

```sh
pip install pygame
```

For more info you can read in here [link](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/)

Comment: already I am install this package but not working

Comment: @TusharPatil are you choice right python version ?

Comment: I am using python3.8.2 version

Comment: @TusharPatil can you give me error logs

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0dev10 (from versions: 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4.dev0, 1.9.4rc1, 1.9.4, 1.9.5rc1, 1.9.5rc2, 1.9.5, 1.9.6rc1, 1.9.6rc2, 1.9.6, 2 .0.0.dev6, 2.0.0.dev12, 2.0.0.dev14, 2.0.0.dev16, 2.0.0.dev18, 2.0.0.dev20, 2.0.0.dev22, 2.0.0.dev24, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev1, 2.0.1, 2.0.2.dev4, 2.0.2, 2.0.3.dev2, 2.0.3.dev4, 2.0.3.dev6, 2.0.3, 2.1.0.dev2, 2.1. 0, 2.1.1.dev2, 2.1.1.dev4, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3.dev2, 2.1.3.dev4) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==2.0.0dev10

Comment: @TusharPatil try uninstall all package [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250821/13000260) and reinstall pygame by `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

You could try uninstalling pygame2.0.0.dev12

by `pip uninstall pygame2.0.0.dev12`

And then install pygame by `pip install pygame`

See if it works

Comment: still its not working same issue raise..

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0dev10 (from versions: 1.9.2rc1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4.dev0, 1.9.4rc1, 1.9.4, 1.9.5rc1, 1.9.5rc2, 1.9.5, 1.9.6rc1, 1.9.6rc2, 1.9.6, 2
.0.0.dev6, 2.0.0.dev12, 2.0.0.dev14, 2.0.0.dev16, 2.0.0.dev18, 2.0.0.dev20, 2.0.0.dev22, 2.0.0.dev24, 2.0.0, 2.0.1.dev1, 2.0.1, 2.0.2.dev4, 2.0.2, 2.0.3.dev2, 2.0.3.dev4, 2.0.3.dev6, 2.0.3, 2.1.0.dev2, 2.1.
0, 2.1.1.dev2, 2.1.1.dev4, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3.dev2, 2.1.3.dev4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==2.0.0dev10

Comment: @TusharPatil Then just uninstall all of pygame and install again by `pip install pygame`

Comment: not working....

Comment: Then just change your code and make it use pygame (`import pygame` or something like that) rather than using `pygame2.0.0dev10`

Comment: I am first install pygame using (pip install pygame),after that they say you install another package i.e.pygame2.0.0dev10,instead of that I am install pygame2.0.0dev12 this package install but not work also I am change code but not working,if you have proper solution then tell