# Python distutils - override old py implementation with .so C extension

Tags: python, cython, distutils, cpython

The first draft of a package in my library was a `foo.py` file which I've now superseded with a Cython/C extension, a `foo.so` - however, distutils doesn't automagically realise that the old .py file is gone, so both sit in the site-packages directory after install (and who knows which is loaded when you use `import`..)

Obviously I can manually remove the old files myself, but I don't want users of my library to have to care about this sort of thing.

What is the canonical / distutils / pythonic way to handle this? Is there some syntax like

```
from distutils import setup
setup(..., depricated=['path/to/foo.py'])
```

to indicate obsolete .py files to be removed from install directories on upgrade?

Comment: related:[How do you uninstall a python package that was installed using distutils?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/402359/4279)

Comment: umm, this is quite specifically about upgrading, not uninstalling. the same purpose could be served by uninstalling and reinstalling true, but since `distutils` has no uninstall feature, I don't think this is helpful to end users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `uninstall` command in distutils. Though `pip` can remove the old version automatically before installing a new one. Other installers also could provide an `uninstall` command.

Instruct your users to use `pip` if they are installing from source. Most binary formats such as rpm, deb, msi support uninstalling by default. btw, [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/ConvertingPython) provides an easy way to convert python packages.

You could use `python -v` to see what files are loaded for your module. `.so` might have a higher priority but you shouldn't rely on it in this case and remove the old version instead.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I'll leave this question open in case anyone has a clever way of handling this - I hope there is a better way than adding some hack into my setup.py to search for obsolete/harmful files.

Comment: @tehwalrus: I see no indication in the answer that you should add any hacks to `setup.py`.

Comment: The question is about what I do to make sure end users don't have to worry about this (*"but I don't want users of my library to have to care about this sort of thing."*). They're going to run `setup.py` and that's it, so in order to "remove the old version" as you suggest, I have to put some 'is it there? yes? delete it' hack in setup.py to be run whenever the command is `install` (i.e. when we'll have write privileges to the install directory). I know you didn't explicitly suggest it, but it is required to follow your instructions.

Comment: @tehwalrus: I've added explicit suggestion.