# Different versions of SKlearn on python 2 and 3

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run some code on python 2 and I keep getting this error `No module named model_selection`. I checked and for some reason the sklearn on my python2 is version 0.17 but when I try to update, it says that I already have an updated version but that is for python 3. How do I specifically update sklearn for python 2?

Error I get when running `pip install -U scikit-learn`: `Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /home/ruven/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.19.2)`

Error I get when running `python2.7 -m pip install -U scikit-learn`:

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/67/370aa248f54769a56216707ad7b9af19745e85a603fafa47bde353f327fb/scikit_learn-0.19.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.17
Cannot uninstall 'scikit-learn'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Comment: @Steven I just tried it but I still had an error. I have updated to question to include the error. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you uninstall a python package that was installed using distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402359/how-do-you-uninstall-a-python-package-that-was-installed-using-distutils)

Comment: @dbliss I can't seem to delete the files in my /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory as I don't have the permission as this is my company's computer.

Comment: @dbliss I actually manage to solve it with easy_install. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved using the following command:

`sudo easy_install --upgrade scikit-learn`