# Can't import ChaCha20

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I've been trying to use ChaCha20 for some school work but I can't seem to import it.
When I run the code I get an error

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ChaCha20
ImportError: cannot import name ChaCha20
```

I have tried to import other stuff from Crypto.Cipher (AES for example) and I don't get any errors.

EDIT: 
Even after uninstalling everything and reinstalling pycryptodome (only) I still get the same error any ideias why?

EDIT2: Now I was being an idiot. After uninstalling pycrypto and installing pycryptodome it didn't work because I installed it for python2.x and I was using python3.x to solve it I only had to do was `pip3 install pycryptodome`

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: You're probably using PyCrypto, but `ChaCha20` is only available in [`PyCryptodome`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20.html), apparently.

Comment: python 3.6.6 and pycrypto 2.6.1

Comment: I also have pycryptodome install version 3.6.6 should i remove pycrypto?

Comment: @45Yoda, quote from [docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html): "One must avoid having both PyCrypto and PyCryptodome installed at the same time, as they will interfere with each other."

Comment: I have been trying to delete pycrypto but it says it's a distutils project how can I effectively remove it??

Comment: Heh, a name clash between crypto libraries, that's what you get when you try to oversimplify things - such as package names and package handling. 45Yodo, you may have to ask your friendly admin to solve this. Oh, and [this is StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402359/how-do-you-uninstall-a-python-package-that-was-installed-using-distutils)

Comment: @45Yoda you should install `pycryptodomex` instead: it's the same as `pycryptodome` but under the separate `Cryptodome` namespace (so you will be able to use `Cryptodome.Cipher.ChaCha20` and experience no clashes with the old pycrypto).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cmd: `pip install chacha20` and `pip install pycryptodome`

After pip installing these, you can import the chacha20 module