# Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong

Tags: python, tensorflow

when i run the command :

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

it throws the following error:

> Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus
>   we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would
>   lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you uninstall a python package that was installed using distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402359/how-do-you-uninstall-a-python-package-that-was-installed-using-distutils)