# How to delete an installed Module in Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x

I installed a module with pip in **python 3.7(Win 10)**.  However now I have seen that this module gives me problem so I want to delete this installed module.

I installed the module `SomePackage` with

`python -m pip install SomePackage`

Now I want to delete "**SomePackage**" from my Python Environment.

I have tried different ways but they seem to be valid only for earlier versions, i read it has changed from version 3.4

Is there anyway to delete desired module from Python setup?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/403563/2702249

Answer (score 1):

```
pip uninstall somepackage
```

will uninstall the package that you have installed. Look into this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524522/4334340